# 'unknown' vs. 'any'

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

TypeScript 3.0 introduces `unknown` type, according to their wiki:

> unknown is now a reserved type name, as it is now a built-in type.
>   Depending on your intended use of unknown, you may want to remove the
>   declaration entirely (favoring the newly introduced unknown type), or
>   rename it to something else.

What is difference between `unknown` and `any`? When should we use `unknown` over `any`?

Comment: `Anything is assignable to unknown, but unknown isn't assignable to anything but itself` sounds like rhyme

Comment: `unknown` and `any` are 2 special types that can hold any value in typescript.
However, `Unknown` is recommended over `any` because it offers type checking whenever we try to use the variable.

Comment: Unknown is what most typed language use (named Object in C#, java or AS3). It's the base type from which all other types inherit, and it behave according to a general rule which says you can't assign a value of a less specific type to a more specific type. Any is more like a permissive hack that disable all typing rules, it's a good rule of thumb to avoid it whenever possible

Comment: @Naren we can assign `unknown` to `any`

Answer (score 928, accepted):

You can read more about `unknown` in the [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24439) or the [RC announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-0-rc-2/#the-unknown-type), but the gist of it is:

> [..] unknown which is the type-safe counterpart of any. Anything is assignable to unknown, but unknown isn't assignable to anything but itself and any without a type assertion or a control flow based narrowing. Likewise, no operations are permitted on an unknown without first asserting or narrowing to a more specific type.

A few examples:

```
let vAny: any = 10;          // We can assign anything to any
let vUnknown: unknown =  10; // We can assign anything to unknown just like any 


let s1: string = vAny;     // Any is assignable to anything 
let s2: string = vUnknown; // Invalid; we can't assign vUnknown to any other type (without an explicit assertion)

vAny.method();     // Ok; anything goes with any
vUnknown.method(); // Not ok; we don't know anything about this variable
```

The suggested usage is:

> There are often times where we want to describe the least-capable type in TypeScript. This is useful for APIs that want to signal “this can be any value, so you must perform some type of checking before you use it”. This forces users to safely introspect returned values.

Comment: Anyone coming from C# background, `any` is like `dynamic` and `unknown` is like `object`. I like `unknown` as it is just more type safe. Confusing names though.

Comment: I don't know that this is a fair to compare `unknown` and `object` @nawfal although I think I see what you're getting at in terms of the contravariance and covariance (e.g. any object is assignable to type `object` although for `unknown` any object or primitive may be assigned - similarly `unknown` can be assigned to `any` or itself and `object` could be assigned to `dynamic` or itself). On a side note I'm unclear why the TS docs refer to `unknown` as a top type because it doesn't really contain all types 
¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: How I read it: `unknown` is *I don't know*; `any` is *I don't care*

Comment: More verbosely, `unknown` is *I don't know (yet), thus I have to figure it out*, `any` is *I don't care, thus I don't care*

Comment: So with type `unknown`, your code has to identify a type before you can access any members of that type or the TS compiler will complain; with type `any`, the compiler will not complain about accessing a property, even though that property may not exist at runtime?

Comment: Unknown is a top type specifically because all other types are assignable to it. In other words, not knowing anything about unknown makes it possible to assign any value to it, because there are no constraints.

Comment: This answer doesn't really help. You don't show how unknown is to be used, you just show what we have all encourtered already.

Comment: @basickarl A good example I can think of for `unknown` is when handling an API's error response. And then narrowing its type while processing it.

Answer (score 165):

they are different in semantics.

`unknown` is the parent type of all other types. it's a regular type in the type system.

`any` means "disable the type check". it's a compiler directive.

Comment: These simple sentences make a lot of sense.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "meta programming"? Why did you use it in relation to `any`?

Answer (score 76):

The difference between unknown and any is described as:

> Much like `any`, any value is assignable to `unknown`; however, unlike `any`, you cannot access any properties on values with the type `unknown`, nor can you call/construct them. Furthermore, values of type `unknown` can only be assigned to `unknown` or `any`.

To answer your question of when should you use `unknown` over `any`:

> This is useful for APIs that want to signal “this can be any value, so
>   you *must* perform some type of checking before you use it”. This forces
>   users to safely introspect returned values.

Take a look at the [TypeScript 3.0 announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/07/12/announcing-typescript-3-0-rc/) for examples of type checking a variable of type `unknown` and a more detailed explanation.

Comment: "this can be any value, so you must perform some type of checking before you use it". Let's say I'm writing a reusable function, which takes an argument of type `unknown`, by "you" here you mean me or the ones who consume my function? Who have to do the type check?

Answer (score 54):

any, unknown:

- allow assigning any type

any:

- allows being assigned to any type
- allows calling any method

unknown:

- doesn't allow being assigned to any type
- doesn't allow calling any method

```js
const a: any = 'a'; // OK
const b: unknown = 'b' // OK

const v1: string = a; // OK
const v2: string = b; // ERROR
const v3: string = b as string; // OK

a.trim() // OK
b.trim() // ERROR
```

Comment: `doesn't allow to call any method`, this is incorrect (or maybe just hard to understand?). anyway, you can call any method on a value typed as `any`.

Comment: The only answer to show use of `as T`, which will change the type from `unknown` to `T`.  Very good.

Comment: As I understand now (even using them for some good time), `any` is basically using bare javascript. `unknown` is basically a safer way to deal with stuff you don't know the type.

Answer (score 53):

### `any` type:

The `any` type represents all possible JS values. Every type is assignable to type `any`. Therefore the type `any` is an universal supertype of the type system. The TS compiler will allow any operation on values typed `any`. For example:

```
let myVar: any;

myVar[0];
myVar();
myVar.length;
new myVar();
```

In many occasions this is too lenient of the TS compiler. i.e. it will allow operations which we could have known to be resulting into a runtime error.

### `unknown` type:

The `unknown` type represents (just like `any`) all possible JS values. Every type is assignable to type `unknown`. Therefore the type `unknown` is another universal supertype of the type system (alongside `any`). However, the TS compiler **won't** allow any operation on values typed `unknown`. Furthermore, the `unknown` type is only assignable to the type `any`. An example will clarify this:

```
let myVar: unknown;

let myVar1: unknown = myVar;   // No error
let myVar2: any = myVar;       // No error
let myVar3: boolean = myVar;   // Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

// The following operations on myVar all give the error:
// Object is of type 'unknown'
myVar[0];
myVar();
myVar.length;
new myVar();
```

Answer (score 15):

#### Unknown

If you write a function that only passes down an input to another function, use `unknown`. From the perspective of the function: "I don't know, I don't wanna know". There is nothing wrong with using `unknown`.

E.g.:

```
function buy(item: unknown): Purchase {
  if (item) {
    return purchase(item);
  } else {
    throw new TypeError('item is missing');
  }
}
```

#### Any

If you need to call properties on that value, then `any` is more suited.

Linting might not like `any`, suggesting you to be more specific with your input. That way, if you change the interface from `isItem` to `isValid`, typescript tells you to update your code.

E.g.:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
function isItem(item: any): item is Purchase {
  return !!item?.price;
}
```

#### Calling properties

```
function isStuff(item: unknown): item is Stuff {
  return (item as Stuff).it !== undefined;
}
function isStuff(item: any): item is Stuff {
  return item.it !== undefined;
}
camelcaseKeys(item) as unknown as Item;
```

See [user defined guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) if you're interested, I brought it in because it's one of the few cases where I need any.

From this blog from [ultimatecourses](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/typescript-types-the-any-type):

> Use the `any` type when there are no other options

It's hard to find good examples for `any`.

Answer (score 15):

I am late to the party but will try to demystify it.

```
const canBeAnything: any = 100;
const canNotBeAnything: unknown = 100;

// If we try to use a .startsWith() method
canBeAnything.startsWith('10'); // no error
canNotBeAnything.startsWith('10'); // Property 'startsWith' does not exist on type 'unknown'
```

only way to use the method `.startsWith()` on unknown is explicitly telling compiler the type, like

```
(canNotBeAnything as string).startsWith('10'); // Chill down TS compiler, I know what I am doing.
```

The latter on doesn't show any compilation error but it throws error during runtime because `canNotBeAnything` is a number type and we are forcing it to be `string`

Answer (score 6):

In simpler terms,

- `any` lets you do anything you want
- `unknown` doesn't let you do anything at all without checking the type first.

For example -

```
let a: any;
let b: unknown;

a.anything() // no error
b.anything() // error 'b' is of type 'unknown'.
```

`any` disables all the type-checking Typescript does. While `unknown` forces you to be super strict with whatever type you are assigning.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the mental to easily distinguish `any` from `unknown`.

### What's common

You can assign anything to `any` and anything to `unknown`.

```js
let anyVar: any = 'Value';         // OK
anyVar = 3;                        // OK
```

```js
let unknownVar: unknown = 'Value'; // OK
unknownVar = 3;                    // OK
```

[See the demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhgdgngNSgJwFzXhAvBA5E4AVxFwG4ILLKB6aiAeQGkAoWRFbCAZnKr-4ERaDFs1CRCMANYwA9gHcYSNBEkyFMTvihES5YU2Zq5i5Zx6DLNOkyA)

### What's different

You can perform **any operation on `any`**, but you have to **do a type check or type assertion to operate on `unknown`**.

```js
let anyVar: any = 'Value';

anyVar.length // OK
```

```js
let unknownVar: unknown = 'Value';

unknownVar.length             // NOT OK

(unknownVar as string).length // OK (with type assertion)
if (typeof unknownVar === 'string') {
  unknownVar.length;          // OK (with type check)
}
```

[See the demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhgdgngNSgJwFzXhAvBA5E4AVxFwG4AoWRFAOlBgHMwALCAejYgHkBpc80JEIwA1jAD2AdxhI0EYWKkxseAsTLtOvcgonTZdEIxYRTZ82Y4QAclwAq3PgApdS2dADOED2GQBLRgBKQ2NWK14IJ0k-EzA4AAcQTw8QZDA-cRhA8j8AM0i4xPF8130UbCwcXB9-RlxAiABvclNSmVp6JmZSCwtwnkjo2ISkgGNmEFGRbIBfciA)

Check also the post ["unknown vs any in TypeScript"](https://dmitripavlutin.com/typescript-unknown-vs-any/) (I'm the post author).

Comment: I love this answer, not because it adds anything to the older answers, rather because it's the best to take note from. Great writing and summarization just like your articles Dmitri. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The difference is about what you can do with a value of the given type.

#### Any

When you are given a `val: any`, the compiler won't (can't) stop you from shooting yourself in the foot.

- It *may* be a `string`, so you can write `val.startsWith("a")` (and crash with `TypeError: 42.startsWith is not a function` if `val` is `42`)
- It *may* be a `function`, so you can write `val(42)` (and crash with `TypeError: "foo" is not a function` if val is `"foo"`)
- It *may* be a `number`, so you can write `val * 2` (and get `NaN` if it's `"foo"`)
- It *may* be a `Foo`, so you can write `val.bar()`.

#### Unknown

When you are given a `val: unknown`, you have to do some type-checking before you can do the above.

- You can write `val.startsWith("a")` only after validating that `val` is a `string` (`typeof(val)==="string"`)
- You can write `val.bar()` only after validating that `val` is an object that has a method called `bar` that takes no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer says "unknown which is the type-safe counterpart of any."

However, as this example shows `unknown` is its own beast and it sometimes behaves very differently from `any`:

```js
type Foo = unknown extends string ? true : false // false
type Bar = any extends string ? true : false     // boolean - i.e. both true and false
```

Comment: This answer seems like more of a comment for the accepted answer - not an actual answer.

Comment: @CodeFinity It is both - the question is "What is difference between unknown and any?" and my answer provides a key and important difference that's worth understanding.