# Any vs Generic Type vs Unknown Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, generic-type-argument

Can the Generic Types replace the type any?

I know that it is hardly recommended to avoid the use of type `any` since it removes all type checking provided by typescript. In other words, it is not safe.

What is the better approach, to use unknown or generic types instead of any?

Example of function signature I want to adjust:

```
getTranslationByKeys(keys: any): any {}
```

The type of the keys and the return value are specified on the function's call (array, object...)

Comment: Interesting questions! this thread could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51569567/typescript-3-0-unknown-type-as-an-alternative-to-any-or-generics

Comment: It really depends on the function itself, what does it expect to be passed as parameter and what does it returns? From that line alone it's very difficult if not impossible to know anything better.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Right now there's not enough information to make a suggestion.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mxYBxW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Is it possible that when you say "hardly" you mean "strongly"?  To say something is "hardly recommended" means that it is almost never recommended.  If you are trying to say that it is "intensely" or "forcefully" recommended, then the word "strongly" would be a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to function definitions, I think the blanket prohibition on using `any`, -- often stated as: "don't ever use it unless it's temporarily to help with a migration of javascript to typescript" -- is oversimplified. Specifically, I don't think the prohibition against `any` is nearly as strong when it is used as the constraint on a generic type parameter to a function.  Indeed, I think `any` can be quite a useful type when used in that context.

I don't disagree that `any` is quite bad in the example you give.

```
getTranslationByKeys(keys: any): any {}
```

This is just completely opting out of the type system.  For example, look at this call site:

```
const myResult = getTranslationByKeys(keys: [1,3,4])
```

I have no idea whether this function can execute on the parameters I've passed it or what `myResult` will be when its done (if it even can complete):

Bad; for sure.  But consider the following function typing:

```
function getTranslationByKeys<T extends any>(keys: T): T {}
```

It's got the word `any` in it.  And certainly there are many lint rules that will yell at you for using this, and many texts on learning TypeScript that would lead you to believe this is a bad idea unless you are doing it temporarily for purposes of an upgrade.

But I don't think that's really right in this case.  Why isn't that a problem? Because unlike when you use `any` as a raw type, in this case you are not completely opting out of the type system.  You will, in fact, still have strong type safety at the *call site*. For example, a call like:

```
const myResult = getTranslationByKeys(keys: [1,3,4])
```

will be definitely typed.  `myResult` will have type `number[]`, and (at least I would argue), the lack of a constraint on `keys` is an explicit signal to the consumer that it is ok to pass in *any* type for the parameter.

Now, you *have* given up some type-safety *inside* the function definition, in the sense that inside the function definition `keys` could literally be anything.  But sometimes that's what you want.  You may have a function that can, in fact, handle any type of input, like this (admittedly silly) function:

```
function getTranslationByKeys<T extends any>(keys:T):T{ 
  console.log(keys)
  return keys
}
```

While that particular code might be silly, my point is that I don't see anything about the *typing* of that code that is problematic.  The typing will be strong at the call site and the code is accurately typed in the function definition.  Even though the dreaded `any` is used!

Someone could point out that what I've written above is really the same as just writing `getTranslationByKeys<T>` which you see all the time and, technically, doesn't have the word `any` in it.  Fine, but that doesn't change anything above.  The two statements are equivalent and one shouldn't be better just because the word `any` is hidden.

Moreover, `any` can be used in much more useful ways in generic constraints.  Consider the following example:

```
function getTranslationByKeys<T extends Record<string,any>>(keys:T):T {}
```

This too contains the dreaded word `any` but it is a highly useful type of constraint.  It says that `T` can be any object so long as it is, in fact, an object with string indices.  That's hardly unconstrained and is actually far more precise than if you had said `T extends object`. I see and use this use of `any` all the time in function definitions.

Now, could you use `unknown` here instead of `any`?  Maybe.  I confess I haven't used `unknown` enough with generic constraints to know how equivalent its behavior is.  But, to me at least, `unknown` seems less descriptive of what you are trying to convey in the situation above.  At least from the perspective of the consumer of your function, you aren't intending to tell them "you can give me a string-indexed object with unknown type values", you actually mean "you can give me a string-indexed object with **any** values"--which is exactly what the word `any` conveys!

So, my own opinion is that `any`, when used in the context of constraints on generic type parameters, can be quite useful and descriptive, and it should not be subject to the type of blanket prohibition one often hears for using `any` as a simple type.

I'd be very interested to hear what others think on this topic.