# Dealing with polymorphic values in Typescript

Tags: typescript, class, generics, types, polymorphism

I'm trying to write some parsers in Typescript. My parsers are all instances of a base class, `Parser`, parametrized by types, `A` and `S`, representing the result of a parse and the parser state.

```
class Parser<A, S> {
  parse: (state: S) => Response<A, S>

  constructor(parse: (state: S) => Response<A, S>) {
    this.parse = parse

  // various combinator methods...
}
```

In several cases of interest to me, I'd like the state `S` to be adapted to parsing strings, and, also, to carrying some user-definable payload of type `U`. Thus, the `S` of interest might implement:

```
interface SS<U> {
   str: string;
   user: U
}
```

Then I'd like to construct the most basic parser I can think of: `char`. It consumes and returns the first character in the string being parsed, if there is one, or fails if there isn't. Thus, I'd like

```
char: Parser<string, SS<U>>
```

for any `U`.

But, alas, Typescript doesn't allow *values* involving generics, just functions, classes, etc. [**"Variables can't have free generics"**, as Titian nicely puts it in the comments below.] phAre there any standard patterns to circumvent this limitation? The only "solutions" I can think of are:

1. Make `char` into a function: `function char<U>(): P<U> {...; return realChar}`. I don't find this workaround appealing because there's a runtime cost every time I run `char()`.
2. Wrap *all* my parsers that depend on `U` in a function:

   ```
   function parsers<U>() {
       let char: Parser<string, SS<U>> = ...
       let letter: Parser<string, SS<U>> = ...
       let digit: Parser<string, SS<U>> = ...
       // other parsers
       return {char, digit, letter, ...}
   }
   ```

   Then I could instantiate them all by running `parsers()` when I use 
    them  and have a concrete 
    `U` at hand.

Are there any other approaches that are more elegant or that incur minimal runtime overhead, or an established pattern? [Anyone know if anything like "values of generic type" (is there better terminology for this?) on the Typescript roadmap?]

Comment: `char: Parser<string, SS<U>>` would be in an object literal ?

Comment: No, I'd like to define `char` using an assignment of the type `char: Parser<string, SS<U>> = new Parser(state => ...)`, but this is illegal since a class instance cannot be of generic type. This is the limitation I'm seeking a workaround for.

Comment: Variables can't have free generics. How would you use `char` when would `U` be determined ?

Comment: I'd would perhaps use it like `(char as SS<number>).parse("abcde")`. I'd have to make sure to concretize `U` before invoking any methods on `char`, of course. (But, in my ideal world, I wouldn't have to make `U` concrete any sooner than that.) Of course, as you rightly point out, I can't do this because variable, like `char`, can't have free generics.

Comment: You can use a type assertion as you have, but you could let `U` be `unkown` and when you call `parse` you could specify the concrete `U`. I am not sure how that would work with the composition part of your API though.

Comment: I didn't know about `unknown`. Looking into it...

Comment: Stricter version of `any`. Shameless plug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/typescript-3-0-unknown-vs-any/51439876#51439876