# How to prevent implicit conversion from 'any' on function call in Typescript

Tags: typescript, tslint

Consider the following typescript code:

```
function eatString(str: string){
    console.log(str);
}

const anyObject: any = {
    junk: 3425234,
};

eatString(anyObject); // Compiles ok - by why?
eatString({something: "abc"}); // Doesn't compile - as expected
```

**Is there a way to prevent the function `eatString(str: string)` from taking an `any` argument, either by tsconfig or tslint options or otherwise?**

I initially thought that `noImplicitAny` might help but after trying it and reviewing the documentation it wasn't what I thought. `no-any` isn't an option for me as I still want to be able to use `any` in some cases.

If this isn't possible, is there some reason that I'm missing as to why? I haven't been working in typescript/javascript for very long, but I've already been caught out a few times by some issues that this would have prevented.

Comment: The whole idea of `any` is that it it is the one type that can represent any JavaScript value with no constraints.
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`any` by definition is assignable to any other type, so when you pass `anyObject` to the parameter `str` it will be compatible as per this rule.

You should avoid using `any` unless absolutely necessary. If you don't know the type you should use `unknown` which is not compatible to other types without a guard or an assertion (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/typescript-3-0-unknown-vs-any/51439876#514398762) for differences with `any`)

```
function eatString(str: string){
    console.log(str);
}

const anyObject: unknown = {
    junk: 3425234,
};

eatString(anyObject); // error now
```

In this particular case you should just let the compiler infer the type for `anyObject`

```
function eatString(str: string){
    console.log(str);
}

const anyObject = { // inferred as { junk : number }
    junk: 3425234,
};

eatString(anyObject); // error now
```

You could use tslint to forbit the usable of `any` as a type annotation (using [this rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-any/)) but `any` might stillleak in from external APIs.

Comment: Somehow I missed the `unknown` type, which in combination with tslint's `no-any` solves my problem. Initially I was seeing `any` as what `unknown` really is, but I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: @valjean glad to help, don't forget to upvote and mark as answered if it was useful :)

Comment: In my case, `any` did leak from the external library and I'm looking for a way to prevent passing it to functions. I'm in strict mode and noImplicitAny is on, but still no compilation error.