# In TypeScript, why is my string literal not being respected

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
type Period = "day" | "month" | "year";

let myPeriod: Period = "day";

const anyValue: any = {period: "wrong"};
myPeriod = anyValue.period;

console.log(myPeriod);
```

I want `myPeriod` to have only the values `day`, `month`, or `year`.

But the console prints out `wrong`.

How can I modify my code to return a compile time error any time `myPeriod` might not be one of `day`, `month`, or `year'?

(If I try something like `let myPeriod: Period = "wrong"`, it does catch the error at compile time)

Comment: Don't use `any`.

Comment: Use ENUM maybe better for your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you type something as `any` it will by definition be assignable to any other type. Also accessing any property is allowed and the type of the accessed property will be `any`.

The general rule is to avoid `any`, if you truly have a type that is not known use the more restrictive `unknown`  (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/typescript-3-0-unknown-vs-any) for `unknown` vs `any`)

In your case though just remove the `any`:

```
type Period = "day" | "month" | "year";

let myPeriod: Period = "day";

const anyValue= {period: "wrong"};
myPeriod = anyValue.period; //error now

console.log(myPeriod);
```