# Why can 'any' be assigned to any type without explicitly casting it first?

Tags: typescript, types, casting, any, explicit

Why is the following code snippet not raising any errors or warnings?

```js
{
    let x: number;
    let y: any;

    y = "hello";
    x = y;
}
```

My expectations are: anything should be assigned to `y` as it is explicitly typed as `any`, but only numbers should be assigned to `x` as it is explicitly typed as `number` and if an `any` needs to be assigned to `x` then that should be explicitly cast to `number`:

```
x = y as number;
```

How could the current behaviour considered to be acceptable or as a good idea and not a bug in the first place?  Moreover, is there a way to force the compiler to raise an issue about this and only accept explicit casting?

---

> **Extra Info:**
>
> - `tsc` version: `3.2.2`
> - compiler options:
>
> ```
> {
>     "target": "ES5",
>     "noImplicitAny": true,
>     "strictNullChecks": true,
>     "downlevelIteration": true,
>     "experimentalDecorators": true,
>     "strictBindCallApply": true,
>     "strictFunctionTypes": true,
>     "strictPropertyInitialization": true
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the defined behavior of `any`. This type is at the same type :

- Assignable from any other type
- Assignable **to** any other type (the issue you highlight)
- Any operation is allowed with it (indexing, calling, property access, operator application, all are allowed and not checked in any way)

There several uses for `any`. A couple of examples:

- Allow easy transition from js to ts. While you are converting the code to typescript `any` can be very useful to allow you to compile the code successfully while you are still converting.
- Allow easy interop with existing JS code (just type something as `any` and you can use it as you would in JS). Although you are probably better off writing definitions in the long run.

All this being said, I would avoid `any` at all cost in Typescript today. Typescript `3.0` introduces the `unknown` type which behaves like you expect `any` to behave (ie, you can assign anything to it but it is not assignable to any other type). Read more about `unknown` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/typescript-3-0-unknown-vs-any/51439876)

A few options to rid yourself of `any`:

- `noImplictAny` compiler setting prevents the compiler from inferring `any` if you don't specify a type (it will issue an error instead)
- `no-unsafe-any` tslint rule, prevents uses of `any` in a dynamic way, ie uses are only allowed if they would work for {} | null | undefined
- `no-any` tslint rule, prevents any and all uses of `any`

Comment: The technical description is that `any` is a the same time a *top type* (a type that is a supertype of every other type) *and* a *bottom type* (a type is a subtype of every other type). As you can imagine, this is pretty "weird" and you have stumbled across this weirdness. Modern Typescript also has a "proper" top type (`unknown`) and bottom type (`never`). Actually, owing to compatibility with JavaScript, `undefined` and `null` are also bottom types by default, but you can enable more strict checking.