# Why is tslint flagging properties of strongly typed parameters as any when no-unsafe-any is enabled

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

Having enabled **no-unsafe-any** tslint rule in my Angular project I started seeing quite a lot of results. Digging in to them it is flagging properties of parameters injected to constructor as of type any even though they are strongly typed classes. I don't understand why these are being flagged, I'm obviously missing something simple here.

Error message:

> Unsafe use of expression of type 'any'.

Example component:

```
@Component({..)}
export class SampleComponent {
  private localString: string;
  constructor(private injectedService: SampleService) {
    this.localString= this.injectedService.stringProperty;
  }
}
```

And the sample service:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class SampleService {
  public stringProperty: string;
}
```

Note: If the background is of any use this follows on from this question: [Typescript not enforcing or checking return type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54350507/1534937)

Comment: On what line do you get the error. Using your code I actually get an error on `SampleService` but that is due to the fact that  `Injectable` returns `any` for some reason .. FYI `@Input` also return `any`

Comment: Line and column is the start of this.injectedService.stringProperty in constructor.
Apologies, sample code may not compile as I needed to anonymize it, but looks to happen anywhere where property of injected dependency is accessed.

Comment: Maybe this post will help : https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/2728 I think the issue is from the `any` in the angular definitions, there is a suggestion in the ticket as to how to augment the definitions

Comment: Looks like this rule isn't reliable without altering default definitions for Angular decorators like injectable, input etc. But good to at least get an understanding of why it is happening. If you want to put it in an answer and I can flag as accepted.

Comment: I activated the rule on one of my projects and I added some augmentations to the angular types and it works ok. I will add my findings shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that a lot of angular decorators don't have actual return types, they return `any`. The tslint rules correctly identifies that we are trying to assign any to a place where a decorator is expected.

One solution is to augment the types of the decorators. I activated the rule in one of my projects and these augmentations make the linter happy, you may need to add others as needed:

```
import { Type } from '@angular/core/src/type';
declare module '@angular/core/src/metadata/directives' {
    export interface InputDecorator {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:callable-types
        (bindingPropertyName?: string): PropertyDecorator;
    }
}
declare module '@angular/core/src/di/injectable' {

    export interface InjectableDecorator {
        (): ClassDecorator;
        // tslint:disable-next-line:unified-signatures
        (options?: {
            providedIn: Type<any> | 'root' | null;
        } & InjectableProvider): ClassDecorator;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just had to cast part of the expression as a number

```
this.refundNegative = requestedAmount.value < 0;
```

became

```
this.refundNegative = requestedAmount.value as number < 0;
```

and my linting issue was solved.