# Custom object type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function `fun` that takes a wrapped designated object. I've wrapped it in `Example`.

```
export class Example {
  private __ExampleFlag;
  constructor (input) {
    Object.assign(this, input);
  }
}
```

Here's the function:

```
const fun = (e: Example): boolean => {
  return true;
};
```

This does not work, which is good:

```
fun({}); // no good
```

This works, which is good:

```
fun(new Example({})); // good
```

This works, which **NOT** is good:

```
const v:any = {};
fun(v); // not good
```

How can I have any not match Example? Haveing a more strict type?

Comment: what's the purpose of the `constructor` here?

Comment: `any` is by definition assignable to anything. Avoid `any` like the plague (you can usually avoid it). Use `unknown` if you don't know the type   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/typescript-3-0-unknown-vs-any/51439876#51439876

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir but I am not allowing `any` as the argument to `fun` it's a class. Why isn't it limiting the argument to be an instance of `new Example`?

Comment: `any` includes the class `Example`. It means any type. Is this just for experimentation or for building something? There are legitimate cases where variables can be `any`, e.g parsing input from a http response.

Comment: `any` is special. It is at the same time assignable from any type and assignable to any type, and you can do anything with it without TS complaining about it. Basically anything that is `any` forgoes all type checking. This is why it is so dangerous

Comment: You can also think of `any` as "turn off the type checker for this value and things it touches".  `unknown` is the type-safe representation for "value I don't know the type of yet".