# Typescript lint what's the proper way to declare any type with "no-any": true

Tags: typescript, tslint, gts

I want to use [gts](https://github.com/google/gts) in my project.

It has the rule in tslint.json `"no-any": true`. That rule totally forbids using `any` keyword anywhere in the code. What's the common use case of dealing with it function can accept any type. I'm aware that I can override this rule. But I wonder how would someone handle the situation when e.g. function that executes sql accepts arguments of different types. Is there best practices to handle this case?

The only thing that comes in mind is to specify all primitives types via `|`

```
param: string| number| Date;
```

But what if I'm wrapping some external code e.g. [mysql](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mysql/index.d.ts#L64) in my function that already accepts `any[]`.

Comment: How about `unknown`?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any/51439876#51439876

Comment: Either unknown or use type unions like you suggested.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir yep, unknown works great, if you answer the question I'll accept it.

Comment: 10x added the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think most cases should be covered well by `unknown`. `unknown` is a safer alternative to `any`. The basic idea is you can assign anything to `unknown` just like `any`, but unlike `any` you can't do much with `unknown` without explicit checks or type assertions which is probably what you want (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any/51439876#51439876) for details).

You might still encounter corner cases where `unknown` can't just replace `any` (type parameters with function constrains under `strictFunctionTypes` come to mind), but it should generally work.