# Typescript function can return Promise<any> as Promise<Bar>?

Tags: typescript, promise, fetch-api

I'm creating a type-safe wrapper for the fetch-api, and I noticed that the typescript compiler classifies this as perfectly valid code:

```js
function foo(response: Response): Promise<Bar> { //response received from a fetch() call
    const json: Promise<any> = response.json();
    return json; //Promise<any> can be returned as Promise<Bar>?
}
```

Why is it possible to directly return a `Promise<any>` as `Promise<Bar>`? Shouldn't this require some kind of type assertion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always avoid `any`. `any` by definition is assignable to anything and assignable from anything without any sort of type assertions. When used as a generic type argument, the resuting type (ex `Promise<any>`) will generally be assignable to any other instantiation with any other type argument on that position (ex `Promise<Bar>`).

Since 3.0 typescript introduced `unknown` (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any/51439876#51439876) for more) which is similar to any in that you can assign anything to it, it is not assignable to anything else without a type assertion. So this is an error:

```
let u: Promise<unknown>
let n: Promise<number> = u; // error
```

You might aslo look into tslint rules `no-unsafe-any` and `no-any` that prevent usage of `any` in a project, depending on how far you want to go with banning `any`, and like I said in the beginning I would ban it completely and add exceptions for the few cases where it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Is there a reason why `Body.json()` returns `Promise<any>` instead of `Promise<unknown>`?

Comment: @superbadcodemonkey It would break a lot of code if it did. There is a GH discussion to add an option to use `unknown` instead of `any` in `lib.d.ts` but I can't find it right now and I don't think it will be implemented any time soon.

Answer (score 4):

If something can be `any`thing it can also be a `Bar`. If you look at the Typescript documentation for [Basic Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) it says (emphasis mine)

> #### Any
>
> We may need to describe the type of variables that we do not know when we are writing an application. These values may come from dynamic content, e.g. from the user or a 3rd party library. In these cases, we want to **opt-out of type-checking and let the values pass through compile-time checks**. To do so, we label these with the any type:

Which means that the `any` type completely ignores compile-time type checks.