# Typescript: Create object with same keys but different values

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following initial object

```
const initialValues = { name: 'Jon', email: 'jon@me.com' }
```

I would like to create an identical object except where all the values are `boolean` and default to `false`. Like so

```
const expected = { name: false, email: false }
```

I created the following function which does what I want

```
const expected = cloneWithDefaults<typeof initialValues>(initialValues)

function cloneWithDefaults<T>(values: T) {
  type U = { [K in keyof T]: boolean }
  const keys = Object.keys(values) as Array<keyof T>
  const partial: Partial<U> = keys.reduce<Partial<U>>((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur] = false
    return acc
  }, {})
  const final = partial as U
  return final
}
```

I also created a second version which does not use reduce

```
function createCloneWithDefaultsV2<T extends { [key: string]: unknown }>(values: T) {
  type U = { [K in keyof T]: boolean }
  const keys = Object.keys(values) as Array<keyof U>
  const partial: Partial<U> = {}
  for (let k in keys) {
    partial[k] = false
  }
  const final = partial as U
  return final
}
```

I wonder if there is a better / more succinct way of doing this. In particular I would like to get rid of the two uses of `as` if possible.

In the v2 I wonder if there is any preference for `unknown` as opposed to `any`.

Comment: What's your problem with `unknown`? You don't use the value in your function and there seems to be no requirement to limit the type of your values in any way. So if you want to accept any type an this place, any and unknown should be ok here. (afaik there's no difference here because you do not access the value)

Comment: I could use `any` as opposed to `unknown` just curious if there is a preference in this scenario.

Comment: Unkown vs. any: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I would write it:

```
    function cloneWithDefaults<T>(values: T) {
        return <{[key in keyof T]: boolean}> Object.entries(values).reduce((p, [k, v]) => Object.assign(p, { [k]: false }), {});
    }
    const initialValues = { name: 'Jon', email: 'jon@me.com' };
    const expected = cloneWithDefaults(initialValues);
```

Due to the reduce() call, I don't see an option without a cast. (Either from partial or from any.) Note that Object.entries() requires `downlevelIteration` ts compiler option to be true (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here is [another alternative](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20cloneWithDefaultValues%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(input%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20Object%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.keys(input)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.reduce(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(clone%2C%20key)%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%20%5Bkey%5D%3A%20false%2C%20...clone%20%7D)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7D%20as%20Record%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20boolean%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20initialValues%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20'Jon'%2C%20email%3A%20'jon%40me.com'%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20generated%20%3D%20cloneWithDefaultValues(initialValues)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(generated)%3B) that builds on Christoph's answer:

```
const cloneWithDefaultValues = <T>(input: T) => Object
    .keys(input)
    .reduce(
        (clone, key) => ({ [key]: false, ...clone }),
        {} as Record<keyof T, boolean>
    );
```

Comment: Would still need a final `as {[key in keyof T]: boolean}`

Comment: @david_adler Why do we need a final `as {[key in keyof T]: boolean}`. The current version works in the playground, to which there is a link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write a class with default values, so that:

```
class YourObject {
    name: string | boolean = false;
    email: string | boolean = false;

    constructor(
        name: string | boolean = false,
        email: string | boolean = false
    ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
}

// now, you can create an object with no parameters:

let obj = new YourObject();
console.log(obj);
// output:
//      Object { name: false, email: false }

// then assign whatever strings to its fields:
obj.name = "Jon";
obj.email = "jon@mail.com";

// or create a new one with known values:
let jon = new YourObject("Jon", "jon@me.com");
console.log(jon);
// output:
//      Object { name: "Jon", email: "jon@me.com" }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be an alternative which uses only one `as`

```
function cloneWithDefaults<T>(values: T) {
     const exp: {[key in keyof T]: boolean} = Object.entries(values).reduce((p, [k, v]) => Object.assign(p, { [k]: false }), {} as {[key in keyof T]: boolean});
        return  exp;
    }
    const initialValues = { name: 'Jon', email: 'jon@me.com' };
    const expected = cloneWithDefaults(initialValues);
    console.log(">>>>>>", expected)
```