# Explicitly assign any type in typescript

Tags: typescript, any, explicit

Currently we are migrating our codebase to typescript and we have many places with any type. So I am trying to enforce explicit setting variables as any.

Here is example snippet.

```js
const a: string = 'h';
const b: any = 4;

const message = a || b; 
// Here I would like to get warning that I am assigning any to the message,
// so I would have to write const message: any = a || b;

function say(x: string) {
    console.log(x);
} 

say(message);
```

I am aware about the tslint rule `typedef` (It requires to typedef all variables and not only in cases of any), also `no-unsafe-any` (doesn't work in this case).

Is there a way to require explicitly define any type if you are trying to assign any to it?

Comment: There is also a rule `no-any` for tslint i believe. Other than that no, there is no way to get a warning. Use `unknown` instead and void `any` at all cost

Comment: Thank you very much. Unknown is exactly what was needed. I will add tslint no-any rule and ignore all current any, so we could rewrite them to unknown or type def them as time goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should avoid `any`. `any` is by definition assignable to anything and from anything. It is mean to be unsafe and it also has the unfortunate habit of spreading.

You can use the safer `unknown` type. This is similar to `any` in that you can assign anything to it and is meant to represent data for which you don't have a well defined type. Unlike `any` however you can't do anything with it without a type assertion or type guard. [See `any` vs `unknown`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any/51439876#51439876)

Other that that enable the tslint `no-any` to stop everyone from using `any` and take care with predefined functions such as `JSON.parse` which may still sneak in an `any` now and then.