# Any standard way in @typescript-eslint to cast a return value to 'any' without getting 'no-explicit-any' warning?

Tags: typescript, casting, eslint, typescript-eslint

```
// I get @typescript-eslint of [Unexpected any. Specify a different type.eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any)]

const funcToGetOnlineData: (url: string) => any = () => {
    // const httpData = (some processes to retrieve http request data)
    // return httpData;
};

funcToGetOnlineData('http://getsomedata.com');
```

Casting a return value to `any` is not a good practice I know. However, sometimes we indeed need this. i.e. fetching data with unknown shape via HTTP request. Without disabling the ESlint rule for these lines, is there any standard way/practice to get rid of such situation?

Comment: Why not use the [`unknown`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any/51439876) type instead?

Comment: @CRice Because there are too many restrictions of using `unknown`. e.g. 1. `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)`, 2. `Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)`.   `unknown` type is too difficult to manipulate as it cannot be assigned to other variable.

Comment: Can you give an example, why you would want to keep an `any` type for fetching data? Forwarding `any` inside your application is not a good idea. The web API layer is responsible for a rough validation check for the fetched data. If it's valid, you can at least give it a common object type with string index signature, value types or similar.

Comment: @ford04 Example: I am going to fetch a data from REST API, since I cannot control how the shape of the data will be as I am not the API owner. Let say the API will response different data shape according to different request params, I will map these response data to my custom local types base on what the API response. In such case, at first, at least I need to cast the response data as `any` first and then cast it to my local type afterwards.

Comment: @mannok if you cast it to a local type afterwards, you should still just use unknown. The function that's responsible for checking the actual shape can make unknown more specific.

Comment: Your options are basically, disable the eslint rule, use unknown or define specific types.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this?

```
interface Article {
    items: []
}

function funcToGetOnlineDataV2<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
    return fetch(url)
        .then((response: Response) => {
            return response.json();
        });
};

funcToGetOnlineDataV2<Article>('http://getsomedata.com').then((res: Article) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: This can solve the question partially, but you are assuming you know the shape of the response data beforehand. What if the response data have a dynamic shape?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do so as far as I know.

However, `any` and `unknown` are top-types in TypeScript so just use `unknown` instead. All the values that can be assigned to `any` can also be assigned to `unknown`.

So it seems your choices are either of:

1. Disable the linting rule for that line, or;
2. Use `unknown` instead.

Trying to come up with hacks to trick the linter into thinking `any` isn't being used is not a good idea.

Comment: However, unknown's properties cannot be assigned to known type, which is a big limitation.

Comment: just wanted to add here that for your use case, `unknown` is actually the correct use, as you actually **don't know** what will come back from the API call. the way to work with an `unknown` type is that you can check existence of properties in it, e.g. `if (isExpectedType(unknownVar)) { workWith(unknownVar); }` see fiddle in next comment

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=99&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=58#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDeUBucA2BXCALigGdgAnASwDsBzKAXwG4AoAYwHtqyoB3D8gGsA6pWAALFFAAUAEwRxi8RAEpimDpVkoAfOkatO3YFEokAogA9IbYBFkAVcNFTTLxPNUHUOvamqhLUxJYBV0oUEgOADNAlGRUACIOACMAKwhbRKgAMhyoAEICoLyoRLByDjBsmkDDLh5Pb19qADU4cikMbHwiMuiODmyGKDgQpp8-VkpY6TMrGztHZ2kJlvbyFRV9fiFRCVWvSbaOlSZGIA

Answer (score -1):

Why not just suppress the warning like this:

```
  // tslint:disable-next-line: no-any
    const funcToGetOnlineData: (url: string) => any = () => {
    // const httpData = (some processes to retrieve http request data)
    // return httpData;
   };
```

Comment: that would make typescript cry