# Problem with callable types relationship in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following problem with the relationship between callable types in TypeScript:

```
type CheckExtends<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never

type NumberFunc = (op: number) => number
type AnyFunc = (op: any) => any;
type UnknownFunc = (op: unknown) => any;

type NumberAny = CheckExtends<NumberFunc, AnyFunc> // NumberFunc
type NumberUnknown = CheckExtends<NumberFunc, UnknownFunc> // never
```

([On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFhAxgawKIA9gQHYBMDOAPACoA0UAqgHxQC8UxUEmOBlUA-A1AFxTYQAbhABOAKDGhIUAHIBXALYAjUQDE52RHSgAKAPZg+2RSpEBKOjWPLRk8NACC2EOs3b9hqAENnF2jR8QAG47aQpsZGw9AHdsVy16Dz4NSJjsPwDnENDoeRsRJxBteCQ0FjwiPNN48kL4mgB6BtkTNQ1EHJb88NTY4oQUDCwKwiq2zXIeqNj6qCb+IVEgA))

It's shown via comments that `NumberFunc` type is extending `AnyFunc` type and not `UnknownFunc` type.

I don't understand that because the parameter type of `NumberFunc` type (`number`) is assignable to both `any` and `unknown` types

Comment: Possibly related: ['unknown' vs. 'any'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51439843/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you introduce `any`, you lose a lot of the type safety guarantees in TypeScript.  The `any` type is intentionally [unsound](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-compatibility#soundness) to allow you to do things that the compiler thinks are unsafe.  Everything is both assignable to *and* assignable from `any`; it's an escape hatch from the type system.  Therefore it's not surprising that `NumberFunc` is seen as assignable to `AnyFunc`.  You'd also have seen that `AnyFunc` is assignable to `NumberFunc`:

```
type AnyNumber = CheckExtends<AnyFunc, NumberFunc> // AnyFunc
```

It's best to ignore `any` then, and move on to the other part of your question using the type-safe [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) instead: why isn't `NumberFunc` assignable to `UnknownFunc`?

---

In order to preserve type safety, functions should be [contravariant](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) in their parameter types.  This means that the subtype/supertype relationship between function types is *opposite* that of their parameters.  So, for example, while `number` is a *subtype* of `unknown`, a function of type `(x: number) => void` is a *supertype* of `(x: unknown) => void`.  So the assignability relationship has flipped.  This might be confusing at first but it actually is the only thing that makes sense from a type safety perspective.  This is a consequence of what's known as the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle); if `A` is assignable to `B`, it means that you can *replace* any value of type `B` with one of type `A` and it won't cause any errors or problems.

Let's say I have a value `n` of type `number`.  If you ask for a value of type `unknown`, you'll be happy if I give you `n`.  You'd have been happy if I handed you `"hello"`, or `false`, or any value.  Because `number` is a subtype of `unknown`, you can use a `number` anywhere you need an `unknown`.

But now imagine that I have a value `f` of type `(x: number) => void`.  If you ask for a value of type `(x: unknown) => void`, and I hand you `f`, you might be very unhappy when you try to use it.  You think you have a function which accepts any possible parameter, so you expect to be able to call it like `f("hello")`, or `f(false)`, or `f(15)`.  But `f()` only accepts `number` parameters, so `f("hello")` and `f(false)` are very likely to explode at runtime.  The function you're asking for is very *specific*. Because you can't use an `(x: number) => void` in some places you can use an `(x: unknown) => void`, then the former is *not* a subtype of the latter.

In fact it's the reverse: if I have a value `g` of type `(x: unknown) => void`, and you ask for a value of type `(x: number) => void`, I can hand you `g` and you will be happy.  You will only be calling `g()` with numeric parameters like `g(1)`, `g(2)`, or `g(15)`, so you'll never have a problem at runtime.  That means that `UnknownFunc` is a subtype of `NumberFunc`:

```
type UnknownNumber = CheckExtends<UnknownFunc, NumberFunc> // UnknownFunc
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFhAxgawKIA9gQHYBMDOAPACoA0UAqgHxQC8UxUEmOBlUA-A1AFxTYQAbhABOAKDGhIUAHIBXALYAjUQDE52RHSgAKAPZg+2RSpEBKOjWPLRk8NACC2EOs3b9hqAENnF2jR8QAG47aQpsZGw9AHdsVy16Dz4NSJjsPwDnENDoeRsRJxBteCQ0FjwiPNN48kL4mgB6BtkTNQ1EHKhCqtFihBQMLArCOvbyHpF6qCau53ixKAXOifDU2L7SwdZK1smxygio2KmZgWFxKWhVo+wJjYHygkJrtJqW-JPml+P2oA)

Comment: Thank you very much @jcalz. It's very clear for me now.

Answer (score 0):

As you can [see in this article](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance), typescript functions are only assignable if the target function's parameters are assignable to the source function's parameters when `strictFunctionChecks` is enabled. For example, if you have the following code:

```js
interface A {
    a: number;
}

interface B extends A {
    b: number;
}
type AFunc = (op: A) => any;
type BFunc = (op: B) => any;
let bf: BFunc = x => x;
let af: AFunc = bf;
```

This will error because you cannot assign `BFunc` to `Afunc` due to the fact that `A`, the target parameter type, is not assignable to `B`, the source parameter type. Note that checking if `AFunc extends BFunc` is equivalent to checking if `AFunc` is assignable to `BFunc`. You cannot assign `NumberFunc` to `UnknownFunc` because `unknown`, the target parameter type, is not assignable to `number`, the source parameter type. This means that `NumberFunc` does not extend `UnknownFunc`. If you disable `strictFunctionChecks` in the playground you can see that `NumberUnknown` is no longer `never` and it becomes `NumberFunc`.