# Strongly typing the arguments of the function that was passed as an argument

Tags: typescript

below is the code with the description in which I am trying to send function as an argument to another function and then use the arguments of this function in another function. 
the problem is I don't know how to get strong typing on `service` function argument.

```
interface Todo {
  id: number;
  name: string
}

function getTodos(arg1: string, arg2: number) {
  return axios.get<Todos[]>('/todos');
}

function useAPI<S>(service: (...args: any[]) => Promise<AxiosResponse<S>>) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<AxiosResponse<S> | undefined>(undefined);
  const [error, setError] = useState<AxiosError | undefined>(undefined);

  function doRequest(params: Parameters<typeof service>) {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setResponse(undefined);
    setError(undefined);

    service
      .apply(this, params)
      .then((r: AxiosResponse) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setResponse(r);
      })
      .catch((e: AxiosError) => {
        setError(e);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };

  return {
    isLoading,
    response,
    error,
    doRequest,
  };
};


const TodoList: React.FC = () => {
  const todosAPI = useAPI(getTodos);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (todosAPI.response?.data) {
      console.log(todosAPI.response.data) // I have a strong typing here
    }

  }, [todosAPI.response])

  useEffect(() => {
    todosAPI.doRequest([]) // but I also want to have strong typing for service arguments - arg1, arg2
  }, [])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

You can add in another generic to your `useAPI` function:

```js
function useAPI<T extends Array<unknown>, S>(service: (...args: T) => Promise<AxiosResponse<S>>) {
```

### Result:

By doing so, the typing of the `todosAPI` constant becomes:

```js
const todosAPI: {
    isLoading: boolean;
    response: AxiosResponse<Todo[]> | undefined;
    error: AxiosError<any> | undefined;
    doRequest: (params: [string, number]) => void;
}
```

Thus `doRequest` is typed based on the `getTodos` function given.

### More info:

The `T` generic is expected to be an `Array` type to allow usage of the spread operator. `unknown` is the typesafe counterpart of `any` and was introduced in TypeScript 3.0.

#### Sources:

- [More reading on `unknown` vs `any`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any)
- [TS Handbook on Generics - Generic Types and Generic Constraints sections in particular](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i need. i didn't know about this unknown type.