# TypeScript - Why is any assignable to other data types?

Tags: typescript

As we know, the **any** data type is the super type of all other data types in TypeScript. I am curious why I can pass a variable of **any** to a function which requires a parameter of **number | undefined** type?

```
  let v1: any = 'abc';
  let v2: number | undefined = 5;

  function foo(p: number | undefined): void {
    if (typeof p === "number") {
      console.log(Math.pow(p, 2));
    } else {
      p;
      console.log("p is undefined");
    }
  }
  foo(v1); // output: p is undefined. (1)
```

There is no error in the above code. But I think that **v1** shouldn't be a legal argument to the **foo** function.

Comment: I personally find 'any' to be a hack for lack of engineering. But I'm assuming it is allowed here because it is expected that the developer will pass the proper value to the method. It should be some kind of warning that lint provides that the value may not be the correct type. I just rewrote a ton of code on a project I'm on that the prior people used 'any' everywhere. I had no idea what kind of values were being passed until I reversed engineer the crap.

Comment: Because that's what `any` means. From the handbook it's for times when you "want to opt-out of type checking". When you type something as `any` you are telling the compiler "I got this, don't worry about it". So it doesn't.

Comment: @Elijah it has nothing to do with a lack of engineering, it was specifically included for incremental typing so that you could easily gradually convert existing JS to TS without having to nail all the types up front. Totally agree that fresh TS files should not use `any`, but that's not what it's for: it's there to lower the cost of adoption in existing codebases.

Comment: Why would you do `let v1: any = 'abc';`? If you're looking for automatic type inference it would be just `let v1 = 'abc';`

Comment: @AlekseyL. Just give v1 a value, no special meaning.

Comment: `any` is opt-out of type checking. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any

Comment: @JaredSmith I was unaware of the intent for its creation so thank you for sharing that. I can only speak to what I have seen implemented and the lack of enforcing types by developers and their quick adoption to throw 'any' at everything irks me.

Comment: The **assignability** section of the **Programming Typescript** book gives the rules for whether or not you can use a type A where another type B is required: 1) A is a subtype of or exactly the same as B. 2) A is any.

Comment: Consider using `unknown` instead (see ['unknown' vs. 'any'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51439843/8289918)).