# Does Typescript allow to assign "any" to every other type? How to deal with catch(err: any)?

Tags: typescript, error-handling, try-catch, typescript-typings

I remember reading in the docs that all types are assignable to `any`. But I don't remember reading that `any` was assignable to every other type.

```
function takesAString(x: string) {
    console.log(x);
}

const xAny: any = {}

takesAString(xAny);   // <--- WHY IS THIS NOT AN ERROR ?
takesAString(true);
takesAString(111);
```

[image]

I ran into this trouble in a `try-catch` loop:

```
catch(err) {                    // TYPESCRIPT EVALUATES err AS any
  dispatch(SOME_ACTION(err));   // THIS EXPECTS err TO BE OF TYPE STRING
}
```

Typescript implicitly evaluates catch block `err` argument as `any`, and does not give me any heads up that `SOME_ACTION(err)` might not be getting a `string` as it was intended.

Is this normal behavior? How to deal with this?

Comment: Yes, `any` is assignable to anything. If that's not what you want, that's why `unknown` was introduced, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error because `any` specifically **opts out** of type checking. From [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any):

> **Any**
>
> In some situations, not all type information is available or its declaration would take an inappropriate amount of effort. These may occur for values from code that has been written without TypeScript or a 3rd party library. **In these cases, we might want to opt-out of type checking. To do so, we label these values with the `any` type** ...

*(my emphasis)*

Contrast this with the [`unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#unknown) *(which I think is relatively new)*, where the line you flagged in your code is indeed an error:

```
const xUnknown: unknown = {}

takesAString(xUnknown);   // <--- This is an error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAhgawKYGcCCBlKAJxjAHMAKADwC5EsiTSBKRAbwFgAoRHxCBLHAA2GAHRC4FSkwDcXAL5cu-MPUSUAqmDRg4AdzC1wO-UgC8bRZy6pMuAsTJUtJg7N4B6D4gA8AWgDEABUACxgsRHDEFCQMQkI4Qht0bHwGJyIQDFlkuzTHCgBGYtkgA)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [new feature to label catch variable as unknown](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#unknown-on-catch-clause-bindings)

```
try {
  // ...
}catch(err: unknown) {   // no longer typed as any
  dispatch(SOME_ACTION(err));   // this is correctly error now.
}
```

Comment: why the down vote? the OP is clearly asking how to deal with having the error value typed as `any` and this is how you get it to be `unknown` instead.