# Typescripts `as unknow as number` usage?

Tags: typescript2.0

I am new to Typescripts and I searched for more than 30 min to figure a usage of `as unknown as` but couldn't find an answer. What is the purpose of using `as unknown as number` in the following line of code?

```
public maxConnections: number = process.env[Env.MAX_CONNECTIONS] as unknown as number;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion) might be a possible explanation, `as unknown as` is at the end of the article, just not with `number`.

Answer (score 0):

`as unknow as number` is known as a [Double Assertion](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion#double-assertion). `unknown` is compatible with all types (like `any`) and equally unsafe as `as any as`, but you're only allowed to operate with the value until a specific type is determined. [I don't know (yet) vs I don't care.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any) Linters prefer *unknown* (with *no-explicit-any* rule)

[Typescript: Why does `as unknown as x` work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69399211/typescript-why-does-as-unknown-as-x-work) gives this example:

> `data as Item` will only work if *`data` can be assigned to `Item` OR
> `Item` can be assigned to `data`*. Since this is not true `data as Item` is an error.
>
> `data as unknown` works because *anything can be assigned to
> `unknown`* and therefore `data` can be assigned to `unknown`. => 1
>
> `unknown as Item` works because again *anything can be assigned to
> `unknown`* and therefore `Item` can be assigned to `unknown`. => 2
>
> `data as unknown as Item` works because 1 && 2 are allowed.