# Typescript: Why does `as unknown as x` work

Tags: typescript

I have `data` its type is `ItemDTO`. I want to pass it into a function that accepts an argument of type `Item`.

Typescript is complaining that this might be a mistake because the two types do not sufficiently overlap and if it's intentional to convert to `unknown` first.

*Why* does this work? What is it about converting a type to `unknown` first that works?

Said another way:

```
function foo(arg: Item){}
const data: ItemDTO = {key: 123}
const results = foo(data as Item) // this doesn't work
const alternative = foo((data as unknown) as Item) // this works
```

Comment: Because TS is forced to trust the operators applied. In the first case, TS knows it is not convertible (and thus not directly valid). In the latter, the code loses the initial type information (as unknown) and says that it “could be”. How is Item defined?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

## Basics

`A as B` works if *`A` can be assigned to `B` OR `B` can be assigned to `A`*.

## Your case

`data as Item` will only work if *`data` can be assigned to `Item` OR `Item` can be assigned to `data`*. Since this is not true `data as Item` is an error.

`data as unknown` works because *anything can be assigned to `unknown`* and therefore `data` can be assigned to `unknown`. => 1

`unknown as Item` works because again *anything can be assigned to `unknown`* and therefore `Item` can be assigned to `unknown`. => 2

`data as unknown as Item` works because 1 && 2 are allowed.

## More

This is known as double assertion.

## References

- Double Assertion https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion#double-assertion
- `unknown` type : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wOa67sZyO54

Comment: I do use this at times, but wondering if this considered good practice though? May I have your thoughts on this, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I still believe this is pure magic and sorcery.

Answer (score 4):

basarat has the right answer - double assertion is the reason this "works".

---

The implications - when you cast to `unknown` you've basically told TypeScript - "*Hold my beer I got this*", then you can do pretty much anything.

Example:

```
type A = {
  a: number;
  b: string;
};

type B = {
  a: string;
  someStr: string;
};

const unsafeCasterToA = (something: unknown): A => {
  return something as A;
};

const b: B = { a: 'a', someStr: 'abc' };
const a: A = unsafeCasterToA(b);
```

This technique just disabled TypeScript type safety checks and so:

- Unsafe access to `a.a` (value will be `string` instead of expected `number`)
- Unsafe access to `a.b` (value is `undefined`)
- Unexpectedly `a.someStr` is defined (but TypeScript will be angry if you try to access it)