# How can I type all unknown keys as a separate type?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I'm trying to type the following object:

```
const foo = {
    x: 'hello',
    y: 'world',
    dynamic1: 34,
    dynamic_key_2: 54,
}
```

`x` and `y` always exist on our object but there can be any number of "dynamic" keys which are always of type `number`.

The type might look something like this.

```
interface Foo {
    [key: string]: number | string
    x: string
    y: string
}
```

But this isn't quite what I want because when we access a dynamic key here, we do not know that it's of type number.

How can I rewrite that type so that all unknown keys are of type `number` rather than `number | string`?

*Note that this object is mutable. A random key of `dynamicXYZ` should give us a type of `number`*

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-goldstine-4cnsj4?file=/src/index.ts) illustrating the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an intersection type, but it requires type assertions to define an object of that type.

```
type Foo = {x: string, y: string} & {[key: string]: number};
const foo = {
  x: "hello",
  y: "world",
  dynamic1: 34,
  dynamic_key_2: 54
} as unknown as Foo;
```

Comment: Why do we need to type it as `unknown` and THEN as `Foo`? Why can't we remove the `unknown` and just use type `Foo` on it?

Comment: There's a nice earlier answer about that here @Matt: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69399373/1710523

Answer (score 1):

You *can* (but probably shouldn't... see below for why) do this by merging 2 objects. You still need to use `as typeof`, but at least you can avoid anything super-gnarly like `as unknown as ...`.

Note that the correct type for `dynamicProps` is `Partial<{ [key: string]: number }>`, not `{ [key: string]: number }`, as any given string key might be present or missing.

```
const knownProps = {
    x: "hello",
    y: "world",
}

const dynamicProps: Partial<{ [key: string]: number }> = { abc: 1 }

const foo = {
    ...dynamicProps,
    ...knownProps,
} as typeof knownProps & typeof dynamicProps

// assigning
foo.x = 'str' // ok
foo.abc = 1 // ok
foo.x = 1 // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
foo.abc = 'str' // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'

// accessing
foo.x.codePointAt(0) // ok
foo.abc?.toFixed(1) // ok
foo.x.toFixed(1) // Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type 'string'
foo.abc?.codePointAt(0) // Property 'codePointAt' does not exist on type 'number'.

// type narrowing
if (foo.abc) {
    foo.abc.toFixed(1) // ok
}
```

⚠️⚠️⚠️ HOWEVER, note that there's a major gotcha: if your dynamic keys are dynamically generated or come from an untrusted source, the type checking can easily be broken, causing runtime errors:

```
let untrusted = 'x' // type of `untrusted` is `string`, as it's declared with `let`
foo[untrusted] = 1 // TypeScript allows this

foo.x.codePointAt(0) // runtime error, as foo.x is a number
```

For that reason, it's typically best that you *don't* do this — instead, put all the dynamic properties inside a sub-property of `foo`:

```
// Object.assign + Object.create(null) gives additional
// runtime type safety, as it ensures no additional properties
// are present from the prototype 
const dynamicProps: Partial<{ [key: string]: number }> =
    Object.assign(Object.create(null), {
        abc: 1,
    })

const foo = {
    x: "hello",
    y: "world",
    dynamicProps,
}

foo.x // string
foo.dynamicProps.x // number | undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's not intended to be mutable, you can use TypeScript's reasonably new [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to ensure that your `foo` object meets your type constraint, but then type it using `as const` so TypeScript will also know exactly what fields they have as well as their values:

```js
interface Foo {
  [key: string]: number | string;
  x: string;
  y: string;
}

const foo = {
  x: "hello",
  y: "world",
  dynamic1: 34,
  dynamic_key_2: 54
} as const satisfies Foo;

const valTypeShouldBeNumber = foo["dynamic1"]; // Type: 34
console.log(valTypeShouldBeNumber);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIDaA1hAJ4BcyAzmFKAOYC6VIArgLYBG0yAPjTqMA3PmQAPKrXogGogpUEy5uAL65cCdCFrIYmZAF4cYycgBEACwgAbG+nMAaMYvMB3dFBsATJ2O9kIHAcwAgAjFQAzAAszgQBQSEIAPqkZMkATFQArNFqyHDUyFo6YDRwYMDUMMAQRRjoopraugBucDYAKmQADhAAypbobD4AQhAAcpw8UEZ6mITmCcGhYeZMwsgA9FvI3X1ReSXU6DYQAHT2DAAU7V29A0Mj3uNT3NAAlKJAA)

Comment: It is mutable, I should have clarified, so in this case although `dynamic1` would work. `dynamicXYZ` should also yield type `number`

Comment: I've updated the example sandbox to clarify accordingly

Comment: Hmm, I just had a go at a similar approach using `satisfies` that annotates a different type on your `foo` variable instead of using `as const` like in my example. But I haven't found a way to define a type that has all string keys typed as `number` *except* for `x` and `y` being typed as `string`. So... hopefully that helps you get part of the way, but I don't think I have a complete answer I can give you.

Comment: @unmitigated above came up with a nice one :)