# Type Guard to make sure a variable is an object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Normally, to determine variable type in TypeScript, I can do something like this:

```
if (typeof payload === 'string') {
    console.log(payload) // const payload: string
}
```

But this one doesn't work:

```
if (typeof payload === 'object') {
    console.log(payload) // const payload: any
}
```

[Here's typescript playground with some non-working examples I ended up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgQwJ4BsQICYC4YLEmAXhgG9ccBGGAXwChaBLAMxgAook4BTEFxVdBiKFiAcmgAnBmADmogJSlaMFTAD0amABUAFgwgwO3GDICuCCUIDuICQGsIy1aEggUXAHRoZrfmkyKGjAu0PDI-tgwktIytHSMLOycPHzhgsJiIABGAFZcwFAKSqrqmrr6MOBcMBggXBBgolBOKiFunt6+aQGlweChfoI4eEhx9Mxsg5gwAIQiMGCmKCgwAGSrhsm8YQLTIpm5+YWKJC29AHK2hnoGVWdt7l4gPlMYgZohsK-D+GMJk90hNJoHhgCkYAB5Q4FE5nIKXCTXCp3EoPDrPLq7N69T47CI-UbUIA)

Question:

How do I make a type guard for an object?

Question*:

How do I make a type guard for a specific shape of object?

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14706877/1024832  The first comment on that particular answer may be enlightening too.

Comment: Hi Jerry, I may be missing something but your code on typescriptlang.org/play seems to work as expected, no?

Comment: @JacopoLanzoni `payload !== null && typeof payload === 'object'` check doesn't seem to work as "expected", it seems to be a sufficient check to ensure a variable is an object, but maybe I'm missing something, since TS doesn't count on that. Anyway, this answer looks pretty good actually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64951336/3720305, and may easily cover specific shapes of objects, though for a simple cases with "just an object" a function definition seems a bit excessive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a regular typeguard?

```
if (isObject(payload)) {
    console.log(payload)
}

function isObject(payload: any): payload is object {
    return typeof payload === "object"
}
```

Comment: May easily cover specific shapes of objects (which is good), though for a simple cases with "just an object" a function definition seems a bit excessive, but it seems it's the only way. I didn't know about "variable *is* type" syntax. Thanks!

Comment: This is not good. For example `null` and array are also objects. You have to check for null, array and maybe more. And you should never use `object` as type. It's like `any`. Use e.g. `Record<string, unknown>` (`unknown` or whatever). It's compatible to `object`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `object` can mean a lot in JavaScript. It's like `any`. For example `null` and arrays are also objects, when using `typeof`.

In TypeScript you should prefer using e.g. `Record<string, unknown>` over `object`. In this example `unknown` or whatever you want. `Record<key, value>`. It's compatible with `object` and better to debug. ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)).

Here is an example to check for an object, which is not `null` or array.

```
const isObject = (input: unknown): input is Record<string, unknown> => {
  return typeof input === 'object' && input !== null && !Array.isArray(input);
};
```

But keep in mind that `object` validation is not trivial (in any language). It also depends on your case. For example if you want to check for an instance of a class you could use `instanceof`. ...

Answer (score 3):

Note that part of your problem is based on the usage of `any`. This type is not recommended for use in new code since Typescript 3.0, which [introduced the type `unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any) for the example.

Applied to your case, we can easily check that just replacing `any` with `unknown` in the initial variable definition makes things much better:

```
const payload: unknown = { a: 1 }

if (typeof payload === 'object') {
    // This type guard works, but narrows to object | null, since typeof null === 'object'
    console.log(payload) // const payload: object | null
}

if (payload !== null && typeof payload === 'object') {
    // This one narrows to object | null too; this looks like a quirk in the algorithm
    console.log(payload) // const payload: object | null
}

if (typeof payload === 'object' && payload !== null) {
    // This one works, since payload is first narrowed to object | null, and then you explicitly exclude null
    console.log(payload) // const payload: object
}

if (payload instanceof Object) {
    // This one works, too
    console.log(payload) // const payload: object
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgQwJ4BsQICYC4YFcwDWYIA7mDALwwDeMCOAjDAL4BQrAlgGYwAUUSOAFMQPRKnQZKFKgHJoAJw5gA5rICUNVjB0wA9HpgAVABYcIMAcJgrcCBVJIgFBCNt2hIIFEIB0aFV5xNExNAxhPaHhkEOwYRWUVVjZOHn5BETEYyWk5EAAjACshYCgNLV19Q1NzGHAhGAwQIQsoEBAAGhh83FgwewVSVpA6opLYAB8YMFwUFC6IZWAGq0zp2ZRcmFkC4tLZdx1I7z8AoOzQqojwKODJHF3xmCmZueT2bj47zBgAQhl1nMYAAyYGWDKiaISH4yPJjfaaaiHK41Cz1aYDIaWEaPUrPQGbNojZHHHz+ECBb4YMKGSKwKkPeGTAnvVJ8VaQqlbHZM2QgsFc-5UV4oRHI8KoupgBpOFwQBZLBpc2pcDgKKL9BSDEhCKRtUZ7ZkiroIMB6kxCchIEC4GBCAAecBQHGAHCgKCQdvtwBQuAwDRFJJuJ3JlIu1KudKhsUZhtZn3O0KkymgpuWkIA8kyxZUJWY0dKYLLXEGvGSzlSaddIPTw7HxskgA)

Comment: That's absolutely good answer, thank you! Though I expressively set `any` because it's what I get from a library, and I can't change that. Good to know about `unknown`! (I might cast any to unknown though...)

Comment: I suppose since this doesn't answer how to ensure the object has a specific shape, and it works only for plain objects, another answer deserves to be "accepted" just a bit more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64951336/3720305 (since more universal). Anyway, thanks for the insight again: very good precaution

Comment: Well, since anything is assignable to `unknown`, you always can just assign incoming `any` to your own `unknown`, without any casts (pun unintended).