# variables type unknown not accessible typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

What if I use a first-class function that is stored in a variable which is an `unknown` type. Trying to do so getting the following compiler error.

> error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.

```
    let somethingany : unknown; 
    let somethingunknown : unknown;
    const loadUnkown: unknown  = (params: unknown) : unknown=>{  <--- exactly her is the mistake
        if(typeof params == 'string'){
            return params.trim();
        }
    }
    
    
    somethingany = loadUnkown('werwq'); <----//eror here
    console.log(somethingany.trim());
    
    somethingunknown = loadUnkown('werwer');  <----//eror here
    if(typeof somethingunknown == 'string'){
        console.log(somethingunknown.trim());
    }
```

Though `any` is working precisely.

```
let somethingany : any;
let somethingunknown : any;
const loadString: any = (params: any): any =>{
    return params;
}

somethingany = loadString('asdasdsad');
console.log(somethingany.trim());

somethingunknown = loadString('asdasdsad');
if(typeof somethingunknown == 'string'){
    console.log(somethingunknown.trim());
}
```

Need to know why `const loadUnkown: unknown = ()=>{}`  is a problem

Comment: Here is an unswer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any

Comment: no, not helping not looking for the difference between any vs unknown. Need to know why const loadUnkown: unknown is a problem

Comment: Because unknown is not callable. try `if(typeof loadUnkown === "function") { loadUnknown("string");}`

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze can you explain in an answer

Comment: You already have the answer linked but here it is again :) ['unknown' vs. 'any'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any)

Comment: @MikeS. already mentioned not the same question.

Comment: It's not the same question, but the answer is the same. Thus, it pretty much is the same question

Comment: @MikeS. not the same thing. check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested here is my answer. Your question does not make a lot of sense as the the variable `foo` already has a type in your example (type: `(params: unknown) => unknown`) if you delete the `unknown`. But I assume that's just for the sake of demonstration.

If you define the function  `foo` as unknown the typescript compiler does not know which type foo has.

The **good** thing about this is that whoever uses this variable **has to do a typecheck** before the typescript compiler lets him pass.

```
const foo: unknown = (params: unknown): unknown => {
    return null;
}
// not working -> the typescript compiler says:
// This expression is not callable.
// Type '{}' has no call signatures.
foo('werwq');
```

So the one using that variable has to do a typecheck first and the typescript compiler let's the user of the variable use it as function.

```
if (typeof foo === "function") {
    foo('werwq');
}
// or even
switch (typeof foo) {
    case "function":
        foo("a");
}
```

Comment: Make sense this unknown type apply to the variables  so it requires a type check 