# what's the difference between Record<string, any> and Record<string, unkown> in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend

I am practicing with the type, and then encountered this kind of problem, I read some posts and still can’t figure it out why.

```
type A = (() => true) extends Record<string, any> ? true : false; // => true
type B = (() => true) extends Record<string, unknown> ? true : false; // false
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['unknown' vs. 'any'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any)

Comment: I know some basic behaviors about unkown, but these cannot explain the behavior of the sample code

Answer (score 0):

### **TL;DR:**

The `Record<string, unknown>` is an equivalent to `{ [index: string]: unknown }` which since version 3.5 **is not a valid wildcard assignment target.** [See documented breaking change.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes/83af27fca396d172b4d895d480b10c3bacf89112#-k-string-unknown--is-no-longer-a-wildcard-assignment-target)

### **Short answer:**

We know that we can assign anything to both `any` and `unknown`:

```
const a: any = undefined; // OK
const b: unknown = undefined; // OK
```

So we could expect both of the OP examples to behave the same way.
To understand why they differ, we must unthink the `unknown`.

How did this behave when we didn't have the `unknown` type?
Consider the third option:

```
type C = (() => true) extends Record<string, {}> ? true : false;
//   ^? false
```

This behaves like the `unknown` but, just to be clear, they are different when it comes to the assignability:

```
const c: {} = undefined
// ERR: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{}'.
```

So now, instead of the `extends` clause, let's test the assignability with a function call:

```
// Note: the generic T parameter is unconstrained
function id<T>(arg: Record<string, T>) {
  return arg;
}

id(() => true) // ERR (correct)
```

Before TS v3.5, this failed similarly like our `C` example. Back then the unconstrained generic type `T` was initialized to `{}` by default:

```
id<{}>(() => true) // ERR
```

**This is correct**, as there is no rule to permit function to be assigned into `{ [k: string]: {} }`.

So with [the changes from v3.5](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes/83af27fca396d172b4d895d480b10c3bacf89112#typescript-35) **the `unknown` as the new implicit generic constraint**, would behave incorrectly:

```
id<unknown>(() => true) // OK?!
```

Because now we would assign into `{ [k: string]: unknown }` which means any object, including function.

So that's why TS 3.5 had to disallow to assign to `{ [k: string]: unknown }`, with objects being the exception.

So now the call with uninitialized generic parameter still correctly fails:

```
id(() => true) // ERR (correct)
```

### **Long answer**:

> Disclaimer: this is not an exact answer, but only exploration of the resolution/assignability process happening when we assign types to `Record`. Nevertheless it outlines that something weird, or not standard goes under the hood with **the assignment to the string index signature**.

The `Record` is defined as:

```
type Record<K extends string | number | symbol, T> = { [P in K]: T; }
```

When we substitute the generic parameters, we get:

```
type AnyRecord = {[x: string]: any};
type UnknownRecord = {[x: string]: unknown};
```

We verify that it has equivalent behavior:

```
type A = (() => true) extends AnyRecord ? true : false
//   ^? type A = true

type B = (() => true) extends UnknownRecord ? true : false
//   ^? type B = false
```

Now we remember, that TypeScript has structural typing. Also we know, that the `extends` tests for assignability from the left-hand side into the right-hand side. Or better, the LH is a subset of RH e.g.

```
5 extends number ? true : false // true
```

In the Any/UnknownRecords we clearly see, that there are **index signatures** so TypeScript will search for the index in the function type. We can do it manually:

```
// ERR: Type '() => boolean' has no matching index signature for type 'string'.
type R1 = (() => true)[string]
//   ^? any
```

Now this is interesting! When we access the string index signature manually, we get an error. While in the `extends` clause the string index signature is not a problem and the evaluation proceeds! **Likely there are different priorities in the resolution process.**

How does TS behave for other index signature, let's say `number`?

```
type C = (() => true) extends Record<number, any> ? true : false;
//  ^? type C = false
type D = (() => true) extends Record<number, unknown> ? true : false;
//  ^? type D = false
```

Aha! It's false in both cases. Let's verify also the manual indexing:

```
// ERR: Type '() => boolean' has no matching index signature for type 'number'
type R2 = (() => true)[number]
//   ^? any
```

We get the "no matching signature" error as with the `string`. So this illustrates, that the compiler for some reason "passed" the `string` index signature before.

Now, how can we verify if there is an index signature for the function? First, commonly we use the indexed access for array, e.g. `arr[0]` to get the first element:

```
type Item = (number[])[number];
//   ^? number
```

Here we see, we no longer get `any`, like with a function. This means that array is indexable by numbers by default. What about `string`?

```
type Char = "str"[number];
//   ^? string
```

Yes, when we access string by a numeric index, we get back another string:
`"str"[2] === "r" // true`

So how does TypeScript knows all of this? These index signatures are defined in the library types in the `lib.d.ts`. For example here are definitions for [the Array](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/5b7344ef52fd72e454f87f4f02a52ece38a5dee2/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1484) and [the String](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/5b7344ef52fd72e454f87f4f02a52ece38a5dee2/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L513) index signatures used above.

Now, getting back to the function. Does it have the string index signature? [No.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/5b7344ef52fd72e454f87f4f02a52ece38a5dee2/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L257) Which matches our result `R1` above. But the functiion does have index signature for a [`Symbol.hasInstance` defined in a later version.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/5b7344ef52fd72e454f87f4f02a52ece38a5dee2/src/lib/es2015.symbol.wellknown.d.ts#L146)

So the fact that there is at least one index signature on the function type, is the reason why the matching did not fail immediately. Perhaps the left hand side path reached the any, which is assignable to the `AnyRecord`:

```
type PossibleExpandedLeftHandSide = {
  [x: string]: (() => true)[string]
};

type E = PossibleExpandedLeftHandSide extends AnyRecord ? true : false;
//   ^? true
type F = PossibleExpandedLeftHandSide extends UnknownRecord ? true : false;
//   ^? true
```

Here we see that if that would be the case, the version with Unknown would have the same result, **so this again indicates there is a custom resolve process.**

Otherwise, we know, that **assigning to** any and unknown works the same. But the difference is that `any` is assignable to narrow types (e.g. boolean) while the `unknown` is not assignable. And so we can verify that the assignability did not play role - the extends attempted to assign from left to right hand side.

```
// Type '"user"' is not assignable to type '"admin"'.
const user: Record<"role", "admin"> = {role: "user"}

// check error to see assignability direction
const user: Record<"role", "admin"> = {role: "user"}

type G = {role: "user"} extends  Record<"role", string> ? true : false;
//   ^? true  ("user" extends string)
type H = {role: "user"} extends  Record<"role", "admin"> ? true : false;
//   ^? false ("user" not extends "admin")
```

[Checkout Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggDFAvFAFCglEgfFYAnAVwkwgA9gIA7AEwGcoAlCAYwHs9qAeW-AS0oDmAGigBDSiBwB+XIWgAuKADNRAG1oQA3FAD0O7LKIAoPVDMA9KUdCQoAIQTI0mRDnxES5KnUYt2XHjx+YSgCSgBrSlYAd0ppQwVlNQ1tUxV1CBN9Cxkja3BoGAkmNg4kKABvIzMzAG1ealIofihA4IBdRXEQIwBfPJtoAFUIqNiS-3Kqmqha8MU2wU7Q0ZjKPoGC2HLnA3diKDIKGnoikAmymX2oRXSNLJrLXC2AMV48HnL9-Ns7HYw9nJPMcfCNImsLtQoFc5DckhkHjlnrYAMp+GjlO6ZH7QBgARn+LjcQNqiwE7URUCem1sAGFCYCPIcvCdfKUuJQCABbABGEDwIm68Wut2SWkRT0GUHpyCxOKgABEGa4EsDvPRIZxObz+SIwuDYsLYaKMpoJVctkrZWKabiAEzK4keWravl4CmmJG2qAASQoXJ2rv5tXa6Bd3Ld7TNnqpVnltIAFqI8OUyeGde7KZZvQAFVi0Wi8HmqCAAUVIYHE1Ag1AAMhAlMAABJVlENaDIaazUgLPhLRS7FX7MNkim9M3y0vlPMFosl8uVmg1+uNls0NvV5kg07FPyXBJwrHR7Kx+Uvaf5wvFssVqvLhvN1vtrfqqBgsaUSHQg8mlJZuMPMwCYsOEhx4Hg7C4KwrQQNAoizgIlCiDyvCqLwoBQNQ7wsMAvCsOsbCUJ8BAaHgiiagARBBJYUSIFGiNQXL8BROCdtRECKBRJH8hR-TygA4lM7GcdxeC8S+rJsv4nBUawNEiGSRpEIeYrHo8VhSk2QlyRxUBcaR4lHK+UkcDJ7G0XpDFMZQLHfiK8J-jG2ZAA)

Comment: Why are you sometimes using a type literal and sometimes `typeof`?

Comment: Literal was from the OP, while I've used `typeof` while constructing the answer, so it stayed there. Thanks for pointing this out. I've updated playground and answer to use only literal types. @Bergi

Answer (score -1):

The basic difference between `any` and `unknown` is the way we assign it into other variables. `unknown` is type-safe, so it is impossible when you assign a variable with `unkown` to other variables with a specific type.

I think you can read more about these two posts.

1. ['unknown' vs. 'any'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any)
2. https://mariusschulz.com/blog/the-unknown-type-in-typescript

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why an arrow function *is a* `Record<string, any>` but *is not a* `Record<string, unknown>`.