# How to properly narrow `unknown` type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

tl;dr why does

```js
const func = (a: unknown) => {
  if (a && typeof a === 'object' && 'b' in a) {
    a.b;
  }
};
```

Give the following error message

```
Property 'b' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

?

Edit: After looking into this more closely I have an even more minimal example.  So let me rephrase my question:

**How to probably narrow `object` type in TypeScript?**

tl;dr why does

```
const func = (a: object) => {
  if ('b' in a) {
    a.b;
  }
```

give the following error message:

```
Property 'b' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any

Comment: @novarx thank you.  I think I have a pretty good understanding of the difference between `any` and `unknown`.  If this were `a: any` this wouldn't even be a question.  However, `unknown` is a good default, instead of `any`

Comment: maybe this will be of help https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: regarding your edit. Don't use the object type in typescript. a better reference would be `Record<string, unknown>` which would describe an object with any keys with an unknown type on the value of this key. If you do this typescript can narrow down the correct property. Have a look at [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAKAhgLhgJQFNQAnAEwB5oSBLMAcwBoYkBrMEAdzAD4BKNDxgBvALAAoGDBpxMAcgBGc6WBhYBYyVLUA6BQG4JUgL4TjQA)

Comment: That makes sense.  But the reason I want this is because of the initial question.  Is there a way I can narrow `unknown` to `Record<string, unknown>`?

Answer (score 9):

You should have a closer look at [custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). They basically let the compiler know, that if the condition passes, the checked value will have a specific type.

In your case:

1. Define a custom type guard

```
const hasB = (value: unknown): value is { b: unknown } => {
  return (
    typeof value === 'object'
    && value !== null
    && 'b' in value
  );
}
```

2. Check your value with it

```
const func = (a: unknown) => {
  if (hasB(a)) {
    a.b;
  }
};
```

[Playgound example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgQwgIRgXhgCgG4IDYCuApgFwwFgDWYIA7mAJRm6FEwCWEMA3jAEZkK1OmBgBfdAD4eAWABQMGACciUAktGZ5ixVACeAByIgAZjBbF0aDAHIQfAFZFgUG9p0AyD+fyWAhNYwYAR4eO6KXjA2fDYcohZE7gwA3PJi8vKgkLAmFMDoWAiCVDT0DFKyChxmmIgomAgM5dzhMAgAdHypVelyYslAA)

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I knew this was possible too, but I don't understand why it's necessary in this circumstance.  The compiler should be able to infer `{b: unknown}` without having to use a custom type guard.  Is this a known limitation/future feature of TypeScript, or is there a reason the type cannot be narrowed normally?

Comment: Look at the first example of [advanced types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types), they have this line saying `if ("swim" in pet) pet.swim();`, where the type of `pet` outside this block is `Fish | Bird`.  If you think of `unknown` as the intersection of all the types (which I believe is an accurate way to think about it), then why does a similar logic not apply here?

Comment: I have updated my question to be more specific

Comment: don't think about `unknown` as an intersect of all types. That would be `any`. `unknown` is the opposite. until proven otherwise it's none of all possible types.

Comment: Wouldn't `any` be the union of all possible types?