# typescript changing variable value type

Tags: typescript

ok so recently i changed my file from `index.js` to `index.ts`, here is a example of my problem

```
let response = "none"
let condition = true

if(condition){
 response = {id: 123 , data: []}
}

console.log(response)
```

but its giving me a syntax error saying `{id: 123 , data: []} is not assignable to type string`
this is kinda frustraiting because i have over 5k lines of code and i dont feel like changing all the variables

Comment: What was the reason of switching to TypeScript then? And what about the code working with those variables, does it expect strings or objects?

Comment: to do fancy function suggestion things

Comment: also it lets me know errors at dev

Comment: Well, it just did exactly that. TS tries its best to warn you both about existing issues and about the ones that might be introduced by some innocent looking changes.

Comment: idk how to phrase this but u dont have to worry about that

Comment: Yes you do. The problem is that sort of thing is *usually* a mistake, and the *whole point* of using a static type system is to catch it. If you have a lot of code like that, you can't use Typescript. At least not for the code where you do that, it would take a rewrite to get it past the compiler.

Comment: when i have switched project to typescript i let there be js and ts together. and in time try to switch all the files to ts. my suggestion is do the same, start rewriting few files and  go on. and this kind of issues you have FIX!. or let there be js.

Answer (score 1):

In order for typescript to be useful, you need to actually type your properties and your methods.

In your example, the `response` variable can either be:

- a 'none' string
- an object with an ID and an array of data

Let's tell that to typescript:

```
type ResponseObject = { id: number, data: any[] }

let response: "none" | ResponseObject = "none"
let condition = true

if(condition){
 // No errors here, because typescript now knows that this data type is ok
 response = {id: 123 , data: []}
}

console.log(response)
```

Answer (score -2):

use the `any` type

```
let response : any = "none"
```

but you will lose the suggestion benefit

otherwise you can also do

```
let response : (string | {id: Number , data: Array<any>} }= "none"
```

and you get some typescript suggestions for those types.

Comment: Suggesting `any` for type problems in *Type*Script is poor advice.

Comment: At the *very least* suggest `unknown` instead of `any`. The `unknown` type [is a bit safer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any). With that said, offering an "out" of the type checking is usually not a good idea. Especially not as the first thing to do. It mostly defeats the purpose of all of TS. ...and then we get more questions about "why didn't TS save me from doing X" in a code littered with `any` annotations.