# Promise callback parameter type not assignable to '(value: unknown) => void | PromiseLike<void>'

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

[image]

[image]

[image]

Typescript does not like the parameter type of my `then` callback:

```
Argument of type '(value: T) => void' is not assignable to parameter of 
type '(value: unknown) => void | PromiseLike<void>'.
  Types of parameters 'T' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

Comment: Apparently `this.booksServices.getSingleBook` (which you haven't shown) returns a `Promise<unknown>`, so there's no guarantee you'll get a `Book` back. Please give a [mre] **as text**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just edited the question with code for booksServices.getSingleBook

Comment: As _screenshots_. Code is text, post it as such. But yes, that function lacks any information as to what it might return a promise _of_.

Answer (score -1):

There's a [difference between `any` and `unknown`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any).

In short for your case - you can't treat `unknown` as `any`thing, or as `Book` like you did in your code.
If your method returned `Promise<any>` or `Promise<Book>` you'd be able to do what you attempted here.

I would go with the latter and annotate the getSingleBook method as such:

```
getSingleBook(id: number): Promise<Book> {
//...
const potentialBook = data.val();
const book: Book = validateBook(potentialBook); // throw an error if not a book
resolve(book);
//...
}
```

You can just assert the resolved value as a book if you're 100% sure it is and always will be, but that's ill advised:

```
getSingleBook(id: number): Promise<Book> {
//...
resolve(book as Book);
//...
}
```

Thanks [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68084354/argument-of-type-book-book-void-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type#comment120336650_68084571).

Comment: That just moves the problem around, because the underlying problem is that `getSingleBook` _doesn't_ return `Promise<Book>` and `unknown` is still not assignable to `Book`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHt0GtkG8C+AsAFAkwCuICYw6IyA5hGBtgBQCUAXMgApToAtsADOEADyssAPjwlkC5FGbko9fkNEQAdMpHoANgDcJlLCHQB3ENLYAiGJjscA3CSLEgA