# Type 'Observer<T>[]' is not assignable to type 'Observer<unknown>[]'

Tags: typescript, rxjs

The following example fails to compile (on the last two lines) due to the error shown below.

```ts
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

class Example<T> {

  readonly events = new Subject<T>();

  constructor(x: T) { }
}

// ...

let example: Example<unknown>;

// ...

example = new Example('some string');

// ...

example = new Example(123);
```

Error:

```
Type 'Example<string>' is not assignable to type 'Example<unknown>'.
  Types of property 'events' are incompatible.
    Type 'Subject<string>' is not assignable to type 'Subject<unknown>'.
      Types of property 'observers' are incompatible.
        Type 'Observer<string>[]' is not assignable to type 'Observer<unknown>[]'.
          Type 'Observer<string>' is not assignable to type 'Observer<unknown>'.
            Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

The project where I am seeing this error is using Typescript version 4.3.5 and RxJs version 6.5.5. The error also only happens if the [strict](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) flag is enabled in tsconfig.json.

I don't understand why I am seeing this error. Every line in the error message (except for the last line) doesn't feel like an error to me because it's saying that a concrete type is being assigned to an unknown type, which is a valid assignment. For the last line (`Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'`), I understand that assigning `unknown` to `string` would be an error, but I can't see where such an assignment is happening.

What is the issue with the code example?

## Edit

I also noted that the error goes away if I remove the `events` property in the Example class.

Comment: You're typing it yourself as unknown with this line `let example: Example<unknown>;
 `. Just change the `unknown` to `string`

Comment: Note that this is a narrowed down example. I can't change `unknown` to `string` because other parts of the code may assign an `Example` of a different type to `example`. I edited my question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It is having an issue because your ***example*** variable is type ***unknown***.

> The ***unknown*** type is only assignable to the ***any*** type and
> the ***unknown*** type itself. See more details [here](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/the-unknown-type-in-typescript).

Use `any` instead of `unknown` as a type for your `let example: Example<unknown>;`.

So it should be:

`let example: Example<any>;`.

To know more about the differences of the two, you can read a lot of samples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any).

Comment: Thank you for your help! Where in the code are you suggesting that I am assigning unknown to some other type? From what I can see I am only assigning `Example<string>` and `Example<number>` to `Example<unknown>`, not the other way around. Any type can be assigned to `unknown`.

Comment: You are using strict: true. It is true that any type can be assigned to unknown, but in your scenario, you enabled strict. If strict is enabled, function type parameters are contravariant checked. In simple terms, If A extends B is true, you should be able to use an A as a B. If you can't, then A extends B is not true. Therefore, even if a string is assignable to unknown, you cannot assign an unknown to a string, hence the error. In any, you can assign a string to any and vice versa. hence the solution.