# How to replace `object` with `Record<string, unknown>`?

Tags: typescript, tslint

Consider this:

```
interface Foo {
  foo: string;
}

const foo: Foo = { foo: "foo" };

function bar(obj: object) {}                   // <--- ERROR 1
bar(foo);

function baz(obj: Record<string, unknown>) {}
baz(foo);                                      // <--- ERROR 2
```

So, ERROR 1 is:

```
Don't use `object` as a type. The `object` type is currently hard to use ([see this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732)).
Consider using `Record<string, unknown>` instead, as it allows you to more easily inspect and use the keys.eslint@typescript-eslint/ban-types
```

Hence, I did what I have been told me and replaced `object` by `Record<string, unknown>` in `baz`. But, now I get ERROR 2:

```
Argument of type 'Foo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, unknown>'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Foo'.ts(2345)
```

So, what's the proper approach to avoid using `object`?

Comment: Just use `object` and disable your linter rule for it, unless you actually run into the "hard to use" scenario to which it refers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Record<string, any>`, you don't get the error.
Just be aware that the object values are of type `any` instead of `unknown`: see ['unknown' vs. 'any'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any)

```js
interface Foo {
  foo: string;
}

const foo: Foo = { foo: "foo" };

function fct(obj: Record<string, any>) {}
fct(foo);
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIyYBcyAzmFKAOYDcuAvrrguiBYSWpsgLw6d0pAERF0w5A3q4YAVxAIwwNoUUAKdACMAVqQBKEVlAAmAHgpUQ1ADTI4IAJ4A%20AJQ4mMdWJfS5CpSqacABeGjr6hugm5pQ0tvIA1iDoAO4grjhQEGCyUCDIWtoAdJAUTEGh3rQENbhAA)

Comment: Wow, cool, but very weird at the same time since any is a subtype of unknown.

Comment: can you explain why any works but unknown doesn’t?

Comment: Here's an explanation from [Ryan Cavnough](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41746#issuecomment-737361754)

Answer (score 3):

This is currently a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) with TypeScript.

You should change `Foo` to be a `type` instead of an `interface`:

```js
type Foo = {
  foo: string
};

const foo: Foo = { foo: "foo" };

function baz(obj: Record<string, unknown>) {}
baz(foo);
```

Edit: If you don't have any control over the interface, you can use this utility type created by Younho Choo on the aforementioned GitHub issue thread:

```js
interface Foo {
  foo: string;
}

type IndexSignature<O extends object> = {
  [P in keyof O]: O[P]
};

const foo: IndexSignature<Foo> = { foo: "foo" };

function baz(obj: Record<string, unknown>) {}
baz(foo);
```

This avoids using `any` which some developers consider bad practice (although I'd argue it's perfectly acceptable practice in TmTron's answer).

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIyYBcyAzmFKAOYDcuAvrrmAJ4AOKAkiACYQAPAMrBqIOGACuUCAB4A8skGQ+ZZOgBGAKwgIwAPmQBeHPmQBtAArJQyANYRW6GMnkBdUvKtvG9XAnQQCkISNExjHBD0UgAiInQY5AZ6AKCwKIAmUh5+YVFxKRlZDHRDE2wo2PjE5OYYSRA9YEDkDTgALwAKTS1SACVddCheWQoqEGoAGmQGuxB0AHcQfQBKHCY2rviV+k3O+IydoA)

Comment: The problem is that `Foo` and the likes are coming from 3rd party libraries I have no control about :-(

Comment: @user3612643 I've added an alternative solution to my answer that supports interfaces coming from 3rd party libraries.