# Why do parentheses affect type narrowing in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, type-narrowing

In typescript:

```
let str: string = 'abc';
let val: unknown = 'test';

if (typeof val === 'string') {
    str = val;
} 
// this code does not report any error, everything works fine.
```

but, if I change the code a little bit:

```
if ((typeof val) === 'string') { 
    str = val; 
} 
// add the () to hold typeof val;
// error report in typescript in this line: str = val !
```

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/DYUwLgBAzmBOBc04EsB2BzCBeCByAhgEYDGuA3AFCiQBu+wiArqgNaoD2A7qtnmCDHIUKyAGYQAFGACeABxDtxdYNiw5cMWGnS4AlBADeFCCaSxeyygF9hYyVLkKl9fWvWbtew8dOaL9awogA)

This is really confusing me, who can help to explain what happened here.

Comment: `let val: unknow` won't work - you need an `n`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['unknown' vs. 'any'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any)

Comment: @jsejcksn Don't think it does - this is about a particular quirk of `unknown` or how TS interpreters parentheses, not about a comparison to `any`

Comment: @CertainPerformance might even be something to do with type guards, not even specific to `unknown`. EDIT: Hmm, no, it doesn't appear to be. Making it `let val: string | undefined` doesn't exhibit the same behaviour. EDIT2: Well, my bad. It actually is a type guard issue: https://tsplay.dev/WK7VKW

Comment: I think that this has to do with the ambiguity of the `typeof` keyword and that TS is not able to recognize this as a typeguard anymore. Ambiguity: `type T = typeof val;` vs `let t = typeof val;` I'd guess that the parentheses turn this into the latter so that your condition is downgraded from a typeguard to a comparison of two strings, no differrent than if you'd write `if(t === "string") {...}`

Comment: see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42203

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript's [`typeof` type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards) walk a fine line. `typeof val` is a string, and you can do arbitrary string operations to it, but `typeof val === "string"` is a special construction that narrows the type of `val` when the expression is `true`. Consequently, TypeScript is explicitly programmed to match `typeof ${reference} ${op} ${literal}` and `${literal} ${op} typeof ${reference}` (for op = `==`, `!=`, `===`, and `!==`), but `typeof ${reference}` has no tolerance built in for parentheses (which is a `SyntaxKind.ParenthesizedExpression` and not a `SyntaxKind.TypeOfExpression`), string manipulation, or anything else.

TypeScript lead Ryan Cavanaugh describes this in [microsoft/TypeScript#42203](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42203), "typeof type narrowing acts differently with equivalent parentheses grouping", with gratitude to [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) for the link:

> Narrowings only occur on predefined syntactic patterns, and this isn't one of them. I could see wanting to add parens here for clarity, though -- we should detect this one too.

It sounds like this is a candidate for a future fix, though even if the pattern were added, you would still be somewhat limited in the complexity of `typeof` expressions that work as type guards.

---

From compiler source [microsoft/TypeScript `main/src/compiler/checker.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/compiler/checker.ts), comments mine:

```
function narrowTypeByBinaryExpression(type: Type, expr: BinaryExpression, assumeTrue: boolean): Type {
  switch (expr.operatorToken.kind) {
    // ...
    case SyntaxKind.EqualsEqualsToken:
    case SyntaxKind.ExclamationEqualsToken:
    case SyntaxKind.EqualsEqualsEqualsToken:
    case SyntaxKind.ExclamationEqualsEqualsToken:
        const operator = expr.operatorToken.kind;
        const left = getReferenceCandidate(expr.left);
        const right = getReferenceCandidate(expr.right);
        // Check that the left is typeof and the right is a string literal...
        if (left.kind === SyntaxKind.TypeOfExpression && isStringLiteralLike(right)) {
            return narrowTypeByTypeof(type, left as TypeOfExpression, operator, right, assumeTrue);
        }
        // ...or the opposite...
        if (right.kind === SyntaxKind.TypeOfExpression && isStringLiteralLike(left)) {
            return narrowTypeByTypeof(type, right as TypeOfExpression, operator, left, assumeTrue);
        }
        // ...or skip it and move on. Don't bother trying to remove parentheses
        // or doing anything else clever to try to make arbitrary expressions work.
        if (isMatchingReference(reference, left)) {
            return narrowTypeByEquality(type, operator, right, assumeTrue);
        }
        if (isMatchingReference(reference, right)) {
            return narrowTypeByEquality(type, operator, left, assumeTrue);
        }
        // ...
  }
  return type;
}
```

Comment: You may want to reference [ms/TS#42203](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42203) also

Comment: @jcalz Nice find! I've added it and a relevant quote to the body. Thank you!