# TS: Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'IParam'

Tags: typescript

```
interface Param {name: string, age: number}

const p: Param = {name: 'tt', age: 18}

const foo = (object: {[key: string]: unknown}) => {
    // ...something
}

foo(p) 

// Argument of type 'Param' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: unknown; }'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Param'.
```

The type I pass in conforms to the type of the function parameter, why am I getting an error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['unknown' vs. 'any'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any)

Answer (score 2):

Your dynamic params should be `any` instead of `unknown`

```
const foo = (object: {[key: string]: any}) => {
    // ...something
}
```

You can check [this document](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-0-rc-2/#the-unknown-type) out for a better understanding of `unknown` type

> [..] Much like any, any value is assignable to unknown; however, unlike any, you cannot access any properties on values with the type unknown, nor can you call/construct them. Furthermore, values of type unknown can only be assigned to unknown or any.

Which means you cannot assign values to `unknown` in your code

```
foo(p) //assign values to `unknown` type params
```

Comment: let temp: unknown

temp = 123

I don't understand, why this works

Comment: @LiuKerwin You can check this out https://mariusschulz.com/blog/the-unknown-type-in-typescript#the-unknown-type, first `unknown` type assignment is called type-correct, but for your case, you're to assign `unknown` to an existing type `Param` (similar to this case `let value: unknown; let value3: boolean = value; // Error`)

Answer (score 1):

This call signature provides type constraints while accepting your `Param` shape:

```
interface Param {name: string, age: number}

const p: Param = {name: 'tt', age: 18}

const foo = (object: {[key: string]: string | number}) => {
    // ...something
}

foo({...p})
```

As for why the spreading is needed in a literal object of the last line above:

> Many objects are not iterable, including all plain objects that lack a `Symbol.iterator` method ... spreading in object literals enumerates the own properties of the object - [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#description)