# TypeScript: Can anyone difference between unknown and any?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type:

```js
type Action<I extends unknown[], O> = (...args: I) => Promise<O>;
```

and some test cases:

```js
// should be [boolean, string]
type TestInput = Input<Action<[boolean, string], number>>;
// should be number
type TestOutput = Output<Action<[boolean, string], number>>;
```

I wrote the `Input` type using `unknown` for `O` and it works:

```js
type Input<A> = A extends Action<infer I, unknown> ? I : never;
```

then I wrote the `Output` type using `unknown[]` for `I`:

```js
type Output<A> = A extends Action<unknown[], infer O> ? O : never;
```

and it doesn't works, the `TestOutput` is `never`.

But when I changed `unknown[]` to `any[]` it works:

```js
type Output<A> = A extends Action<any[], infer O> ? O : never;
```

Can anyone explain why?

P.S. I also wrote this test:

```js
type Test = [boolean, string] extends unknown[] ? true : false;
```

and the `Test` is `true`, so I don't understand why the `Output` with `unknown[]` for `I` is not works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any

Comment: `[boolean, string] extends unknown[]` is true, but `unknown[] extends [boolean, string]` is false, and it is the latter test that happens with function inputs.  Functions are *contravariant* in their inputs.  Functions can safely choose to output something more specific than their declaration (its annotated return type is `string | number` but it only actually returns `string`s) but they cannot safely expect their inputs to be something more specific than their declarations (its annotated argument type is `string | number` but it actually only accepts `string`s).

Comment: See the answer to the linked question for more information.

Comment: But `any[] extends [boolean, string]` is also `false`, so it is not an answer.