# Type checking forwardRef with ...rest property in React/Typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript, react-forwardref

I'm struggling to get type checking in Typescript to work for a React component which uses forwardRef and has a ...rest property.

Example:

```
import React from 'react'

interface InputWithLabelProps {
  label: string,
  [rest: string]: unknown,
}

const InputWithLabel = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputWithLabelProps>(
  ({ label, ...rest }, ref) => (
    <>
      <label htmlFor="field">{label}</label>
      <input id="field" ref={ref} {...rest} />
    </>
  ),
)

export default InputWithLabel
```

This will give component the following signature:

```
(alias) const InputWithLabel: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<Pick<InputWithLabelProps, keyof InputWithLabelProps> & React.RefAttributes<HTMLInputElement>>
import InputWithLabel
```

This will not give correct type checking for example it's not necessary to provide label property which should be required. If I remove either forwardRef or the ...rest property it works, but that is not an option.

How can I use forwardRef on a component which has ...rest property and at the same time have type checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[rest: string]: unknown` you allow any string property to be passed to your input element which (for a reason I do not understand why) renders your other prop types useless. Assuming you want to type your component with a mandatory `label` and otherwise any props belonging to an `<input>`-element, you can extend this by using either:

```
interface InputWithLabelProps extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  label: string
}
```

or combining the types using:

```
type InputWithLabelProps = {
    label: string
} & React.HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but [rest: string]: unknown or [rest: string]: any allows me to pass any property of any type to component? https://thewebdev.info/2022/03/20/how-to-add-types-for-rest-props-in-react-and-typescript/
This is just a simplified example. What if passing the ...rest property to a composite component, not a HTMLInputElement?

Comment: yes, you are correct.

Comment: The reason I wrote down "string property" is because the name (or key) of your property is a string (and always is using React).

Comment: Your suggestion actually makes sense to me now and it will work in my case. Thanx

Comment: FYI: there also is a difference between a type `any` and `unknown`, see this question for more information on this matter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any