# How to correctly determine the type for a generic component

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Let's make a list component that works with an array of objects.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps<{
  items: Record<string, unknown>[],
  selected: Record<string, unknown> | null
  field: string
}>()
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'update:selected', value: Record<string, unknown> | null): void
}>()
</script>
<template>
  <div v-for="(item,idx) in items" :key="idx">
    <div 
         @click="emit('update:selected',item)" 
         style="cursor: pointer">
      {{ item[field] }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Let's try to use it by passing a list of employees.

```
<script setup lang='ts'>
import MyList from './MyList.vue'
import {Ref, ref} from "vue";
interface Employee {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
const employees: Employee[] = [
  {name: 'Mike', age: 34},
  {name: 'Kate', age: 19},
  {name: 'Den', age: 54},
]
const selectedEmployee=ref<Employee | null>(null)
</script>
<template>
  Age: {{selectedEmployee?selectedEmployee.age:'not selected'}}
  <MyList :items="employees" v-model:selected="selectedEmployee" field="name"/>
</template>
```

Everything is working. But, if you do a build, an error occurs TS2322: “Type 'Employee' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, unknown>'".
[A generic component would be the solution.](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/436) But it's not there yet.
What is the best way to solve this problem?
[vue playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has finally been solved drastically. vue 3.3 https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-3 came out with support for Generic Components.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a method.

```
export const wrapSelected = <T>(value: Ref<T | null>) => {
    return computed<Record<string, unknown> | null>({
        get: () => value.value as unknown as (Record<string, unknown> | null),
        set: (val: Record<string, unknown> | null) => {
            value.value = val as unknown as T | null
        }
    })
}
```

App.vue

```
...
const wrapperSelected=wrapSelected(selectedEmployee)
</script>

<template>
  Age: {{ selectedEmployee ? selectedEmployee?.age : 'not selected' }}
  <my-list :items="wrapperItems" v-model:selected="wrapperSelected" field-name="name"/>
</template>
```

Though it's not very aesthetically pleasing. It's better than good old any?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `any` instead of `unknown`. So for your `MyList` component:

```
const props = defineProps<{
  items: Record<string, any>[],
  selected: Record<string, any> | null
  field: string
}>()
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'update:selected', value: Record<string, any> | null): void
}>()
```

Here is a good discussion on the differences between `any` and `unknown`. Unless you need `unknown` for a specific reason, `any` might solve your problem.

['unknown' vs. 'any'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any)