# Why does Typescript not respect the types in my interface for a returned object?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have created an interface to represent the return types of a function. However, if I change the returned type to something unexpected, TypeScript does not error out as I expect it would. See below for an example or see the example in [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=26&ssc=10&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQBVgBneAbwCg5EATALjjKmQHNrESAZTVMxgEYQIAG2CYkHbFHGpaAQRiMkAVwC2AtBxVhavYAqVxVGrQF9KldCqTYYCCEjh8YALTQQAFAEpGEgJ5wVDQ0MjAqUE7BITEIDHAA5ACMAEwAzAkANBwxNAjc+vzOUCrA2bkh0rIGiozJ6Vk5uTp6crVwACwArABsTRYWVjZ2Dk4uAPJIwD6MRKQUTWERY-PuUF7elIPWtvaOzvOEAO4bQU3YjmRwMiRwALwHZJPTmzEXSCSiwAB0IhCsnhum0GLmOGyAA):

```
export interface ITest {
  id: string
  isLatest: boolean
  createdAt: number
  updatedAt: number
}

function testZero(): any {
    return {
        id: '123',
        isLatest: true,
        createdAt: '123',
        updatedAt: 456
    }
}

function testOne(): ITest {
    return testZero()
}

function testTwo() {
    const res = testOne()
    console.log(res)
}

testTwo()
```

The output I receive is: `id: "123", isLatest: true, createdAt: "123", updatedAt: 456}`

However I expect it to not run, as `createdAt` is supposed to be a number, not a string. Why does this run even if the types do not match the expected interface?

Comment: What is your `tsconfig`? You're using `any` which tells TypeScript to ignore typing issues. Your code is also syntactically valid so it can transpile to JS fine, that's why it runs. You should compile in strict-mode and show us all `tsc` output messages.

Comment: Understood. I see that if I use `ITest` as the return type for `testZero()`, then I do, in fact, get an error. Given that, why wouldn't the output of `testOne()` coerce the types into the expected types in `ITest`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Typescript allow to assign an "any" object type to class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373144/why-does-typescript-allow-to-assign-an-any-object-type-to-class-object)

Comment: Just remove the `: any` return type declaration, and it will work fine. You are overriding a precise type to an any type with it, and it breaks the type information TS requires to do the check correctly. You should avoid the `any` type at all cost, and use it only sparingly.